# Add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, syntax

I'm pulling items out of the DOM with jQuery and want to set a property on an object using the `id` of the DOM element.

#### Example

```js
const obj = {}

jQuery(itemsFromDom).each(function() {
  const element = jQuery(this)
  const name = element.attr('id')
  const value = element.attr('value')

  // Here is the problem
  obj.name = value
})
```

If `itemsFromDom` includes an element with an `id` of "myId", I want `obj` to have a property named "myId". The above gives me `name`.

How do I name a property of an object using a variable using JavaScript?

Comment: See also [property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/1048572) and [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/1048572)

Comment: See also [How to create an object property from a variable value in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2241875/1048572)

Comment: I once closed this question as a duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](/q/2274242/4642212), then this target incorrectly got _replaced_ by [Accessing an object property with a dynamically-computed name](/q/4244896/4642212). Now it got reopened—that’s odd and unfortunate. My original duplicate target should at least be mentioned here.

Answer (score 556, accepted):

You can use this equivalent syntax:

```
obj[name] = value
```

**Example**:

```
let obj = {};
obj["the_key"] = "the_value";
```

or with ES6 features:

```
let key = "the_key";
let obj = {
  [key]: "the_value",
};
```

in both examples, `console.log(obj)` will return: `{ the_key: 'the_value' }`

Comment: Is there a name for this syntax? Or a link I can read more on?

Comment: Here’s the documentation on how to [access properties](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), and how to create [objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: @Pixelsmith they are known as Computed property names.

Answer (score 151):

With [ECMAScript 2015](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) you can do it directly in object declaration using bracket notation:

```
var obj = {
  [key]: value
}
```

Where `key` can be any sort of expression (e.g. a variable) returning a value:

```
var obj = {
  ['hello']: 'World',
  [x + 2]: 42,
  [someObject.getId()]: someVar
}
```

Comment: This question is about modifying existing object, not creating a new one.

Comment: This particular question might be about modifying but it's referenced by other questions that are about dynamically creating objects  and so I ended up here and happily benefited from this answer.

Comment: This particular question is [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name#42611234) using calculated property names shown in this answer + Object.assign:  
 `obj = Object.assign.apply({}, $(itemsFromDom).map((i, el) => ({[el.id]: el.value})));`

Comment: @wOxxOm lol yeah why would I go through the hassle of `obj[name]=value` when I could just use your suggestion instead

Comment: I'm not sure what ECMAScript 6 is, but I appreciate it very much

Comment: @ArthurTarasov: ECMAScript 6 is more formally called ECMAScript 2015 ("ES2015") aka ECMAScript 6th edition ("ES6"). It's the specification for JavaScript released June 2015. Since then we've had ES2016 and soon we'll have ES2017, they're on a yearly cycle now.

Comment: Should be labelled as #ProTip haha. Well, most of us use Transpilers for React, Node and everything else, this is the most relevant answer

Comment: Compatibility chart: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility
(See: "computed property names")

Answer (score 12):

You can even make List of objects like this

```
var feeTypeList = [];
$('#feeTypeTable > tbody > tr').each(function (i, el) {
    var feeType = {};

    var $ID = $(this).find("input[id^=txtFeeType]").attr('id');

    feeType["feeTypeID"] = $('#ddlTerm').val();
    feeType["feeTypeName"] = $('#ddlProgram').val();
    feeType["feeTypeDescription"] = $('#ddlBatch').val();

    feeTypeList.push(feeType);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two different notations to access object properties

- **Dot** notation: *myObj.prop1*
- **Bracket** notation: *myObj["prop1"]*

Dot notation is fast and easy but you *must* use the actual property name explicitly.  No substitution, variables, etc.

Bracket notation is open ended.  It uses a string but you can produce the string using any legal js code.  You may specify the string as literal (though in this case dot notation would read easier) or use a variable or calculate in some way.

So, these all set the *myObj* property named *prop1* to the value *Hello*:

```
// quick easy-on-the-eye dot notation
myObj.prop1 = "Hello";

// brackets+literal
myObj["prop1"] = "Hello";

// using a variable
var x = "prop1"; 
myObj[x] = "Hello";                     

// calculate the accessor string in some weird way
var numList = [0,1,2];
myObj[ "prop" + numList[1] ] = "Hello";
```

Pitfalls:

```
myObj.[xxxx] = "Hello";      // wrong: mixed notations, syntax fail
myObj[prop1] = "Hello";      // wrong: this expects a variable called prop1
```

**tl;dnr**: If you want to compute or reference the key you *must* use *bracket notation*. If you are using the key explicitly, then use *dot notation* for simple clear code.

Note: there are some other good and correct answers but I personally found them a bit brief coming from a low familiarity with JS on-the-fly quirkiness.  This might be useful to some people.

Answer (score 3):

With lodash, you can create new object like this [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs/#set):

```
obj = _.set({}, key, val);
```

Or you can set to existing object like this:

```
var existingObj = { a: 1 };
_.set(existingObj, 'a', 5); // existingObj will be: { a: 5 }
```

You should take care if you want to use dot (".") in your path, because lodash can set hierarchy, for example:

```
_.set({}, "a.b.c", "d"); // { "a": { "b": { "c": "d" } } }
```

Answer (score 3):

First we need to define key as variable and then we need to assign as key as object., for example

```js
var data = {key:'dynamic_key',value:'dynamic_value'}
var key = data.key;
var obj = { [key]: data.value}
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add fields to an object dynamically, simplest way to do it is as follows:

```
let params = [
  { key: "k1", value: 1 },
  { key: "k2", value: 2 },
  { key: "k3", value: 3 },
];
let data = {};

for (let i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
  data[params[i].key] = params[i].value;
}

console.log(data); // -> { k1: 1, k2: 2, k3: 3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Related to the subject, not specifically for jquery though. I used this in ec6 react projects, maybe helps someone:

```
this.setState({ [`${name}`]: value}, () => {
      console.log("State updated: ", JSON.stringify(this.state[name]));
    });
```

PS: Please mind the quote character.

Comment: Per above answers, `{ [`${name}`]: value}` can be simply `{ [name]: value}`. The template literal is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of ES2015  [Object.assign](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/object/assign) and [computed property names](http://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/object_initializer) the OP's code boils down to:

```
var obj = Object.assign.apply({}, $(itemsFromDom).map((i, el) => ({[el.id]: el.value})));
```

Answer (score 1):

ajavascript have two type of annotation for fetching javascript Object properties:

Obj = {};

1)  (.) annotation eg. Obj.id
this will only work if the object already have a property with name 'id'

2) ([]) annotation  eg . Obj[id] here if the object does not have any property with name 'id',it will create a new property with name 'id'.

so for below example:

A new property will be created always when you write Obj[name].
And if the property already exist with the same name it will override it.

```
const obj = {}
    jQuery(itemsFromDom).each(function() {
      const element = jQuery(this)
      const name = element.attr('id')
      const value = element.attr('value')
      // This will work
      obj[name]= value;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have object, you can make array of keys, than map through, and create new object from previous object keys, and values.

```
Object.keys(myObject)
.map(el =>{
 const obj = {};
 obj[el]=myObject[el].code;
 console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

`objectname.newProperty = value;`

Answer (score -3):

```
const data = [{
    name: 'BMW',
    value: '25641'
  }, {
    name: 'Apple',
    value: '45876'
  },
  {
    name: 'Benz',
    value: '65784'
  },
  {
    name: 'Toyota',
    value: '254'
  }
]

const obj = {
  carsList: [{
    name: 'Ford',
    value: '47563'
  }, {
    name: 'Toyota',
    value: '254'
  }],
  pastriesList: [],
  fruitsList: [{
    name: 'Apple',
    value: '45876'
  }, {
    name: 'Pineapple',
    value: '84523'
  }]
}

let keys = Object.keys(obj);

result = {};

for(key of keys){
    let a =  [...data,...obj[key]];
    result[key] = a;

}
```