# How to create an object property from a variable value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, properties, object

I want to add a new property to 'myObj', name it 'string1' and give it a value of 'string2', but when I do it it returns 'undefined:

```
var myObj = new Object;
var a = 'string1';
var b = 'string2';
myObj.a = b;

alert(myObj.string1); //Returns 'undefined'
alert(myObj.a); //Returns 'string2'
```

In other words: How do I create an object property and give it the name stored in the variable, but not the name of the variable itself?

Comment: @daniella The object property is absolutely plain javascript. That it is used in a jQuery example is irrelevant.

Comment: For the record, never use `new Object`; Use an object literal instead: `var myObj = {}`

Answer (score 568, accepted):

There's [the dot notation and the bracket notation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)

```
myObj[a] = b;
```

Comment: They're not really "equivalent"; `myObj.a = b` means something different to `myObj[a] = b` (unless `a == 'a'`) but whatever... this is what you want.

Comment: What I meant is that they're equivalent ways to set a property. Obviously they behave differently (hence the purpose of posting this answer) - but they have the same result.

Comment: philfreo: except that they _don't_ have the same result, which is the basis for this question.

Comment: I was just saying there are two ways to set an object, one for when the key is hard coded and one when it's variable. I meant the outcome of the object is equivalent regardless if you use `myObj['foo'] = 'bar'` or `myObj.foo = 'bar'`

Comment: Somehow this method gave me an array `[a:b]` instead of `{a:b}`

Answer (score 564):

ES6 introduces computed property names, which allow you to do

```
var myObj = {[a]: b};
```

Comment: Works with Babel though.

Comment: For ones like myself who develop using Node.js and need this for backend only, thus not worried about browser implementations, this was VERY useful. Should have more upvotes!

Comment: This actually looks like the only way to create an anonymous object with a variable as the key, very useful when you just need to push this onto an array.

Comment: Which browsers does this currently support?

Comment: @Jessica https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_computed_properties

Comment: Great! More browsers support it?

Comment: For a reference see [MDN ES2015 Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) Browser compatibility: `Chrome 47+`, `Edge`, `Opera 34+` and `Safari 8+`. Not supported in `IE <= 11`.

Comment: This pretty much supports a lot of browsers now. Except IE ofcourse.

Comment: Browser Support by now is widespread, works like charm

Answer (score 88):

Dot notation and the properties are equivalent. So you would accomplish like so:

```
// const myObj = new Object();
const myObj = {};
const a = 'string1';
myObj[a] = 'whatever';
alert(myObj.string1);
```

(alerts "whatever")

Answer (score 11):

Ecu, if you do `myObj.a`, then it looks for the property named a of myObj.
If you do `myObj[a] =b` then it looks for the `a.valueOf()` property of myObj.

Answer (score 8):

Oneliner:

```
obj = (function(attr, val){ var a = {}; a[attr]=val; return a; })('hash', 5);
```

Or:

```
attr = 'hash';
val = 5;
var obj = (obj={}, obj[attr]=val, obj);
```

Anything shorter?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can count that as a one-liner, as the function inside has three statements, not one (which is usually the requirement of being a one-liner).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program

Comment: I like the elegance of the second snippet. It makes sense because var does two actions and one of the first is that it "defines" the variable as undefined.

Comment: not very readable though.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use this:

```
function createObject(propName, propValue){
    this[propName] = propValue;
}
var myObj1 = new createObject('string1','string2');
```

Anything you pass as the first parameter will be the property name, and the second parameter is the property value.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a variable to access a property via dot notation, instead use the array notation.

```
var obj= {
     'name' : 'jroi'
};
var a = 'name';
alert(obj.a); //will not work
alert(obj[a]); //should work and alert jroi'
```

Answer (score 4):

As $scope is an object, you can try with JavaScript by:

```
$scope['something'] = 'hey'
```

It is equal to:

```
$scope.something = 'hey'
```

[I created a fiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/o1qjmk7w/).

Answer (score 0):

The following demonstrates an alternative approach for returning a key pair object using the form of `(a, b)`. The first example uses the string `'key'` as the property name, and `'val'` as the value.

**Example #1:**

```js
(function(o,a,b){return o[a]=b,o})({},'key','val');
```

**Example: #2:**

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
(function(o,a,b){return o[a]=b,o})(obj,'key','val');
```

As shown in the second example, this can modify existing objects, too *(if property is already defined in the object, value will be overwritten)*.

> ***Result #1:*** `{ key: 'val' }`
>
> ***Result #2:*** `{ foo: 'bar', key: 'val' }`