# How to set a Javascript object values dynamically?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, set

It's difficult to explain the case by words, let me give an example:

```
var myObj = {
    'name': 'Umut',
    'age' : 34
};

var prop = 'name';
var value = 'Onur';

myObj[name] = value; // This does not work

eval('myObj.' + name) = value;   //Bad coding ;)
```

How can I set a variable property with variable value in a JavaScript object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Have a close look. It seems you just forgot to adjust cour code. It should be `myObj[prop] = value;`. `eval('myObj.'+name)` does not work either as the variable `name` does not exist.

Comment: you should really use more `var` keyboards for declaring variables, use more semicolons, not use `eval` and accept more answers. Done.

Comment: Your question is flawed -- that *does* work, but you made a mistake. You wrote "`myObj[name]`" when I'm quite sure you meant to write "`myObj[prop]`".

Answer (score 194, accepted):

```
myObj[prop] = value;
```

That should work. You mixed up the name of the variable and its value. But indexing an object with strings to get at its properties works fine in JavaScript.

Answer (score 69):

```
myObj.name=value
```

or

```
myObj['name']=value     (Quotes are required)
```

Both of these are interchangeable.

**Edit:** I'm guessing you meant `myObj[prop] = value`, instead of myObj[name] = value. Second syntax works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/dNjvb/1/

Comment: If the object property is a reserved word, the second syntax is required.

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't really answer his question; he's wondering what to do when the property name is in a variable.

Comment: Updated answer there, you have `name` where you should have `prop`

Answer (score 7):

You can get the property the same way as you set it.

```
foo = {
 bar: "value"
}
```

You set the value
`foo["bar"] = "baz";`

To get the value
`foo["bar"]`

will return "baz".

Answer (score 5):

You could also create something that would be similar to a value object (vo);

SomeModelClassNameVO.js;

```
function SomeModelClassNameVO(name,id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}
```

Than you can just do;

```
   var someModelClassNameVO = new someModelClassNameVO('name',1);
   console.log(someModelClassNameVO.name);
```

Answer (score 4):

simple as this
`myObj.name = value;`

Answer (score 3):

When you create an object `myObj` as you have, think of it more like a dictionary. In this case, it has two keys, `name`, and `age`.

You can access these dictionaries in two ways:

- Like an array (e.g. `myObj[name]`); or
- Like a property (e.g. `myObj.name`); do note that some properties are reserved, so the first method is preferred.

You should be able to access it as a property without any problems. However, to access it as an array, you'll need to treat the key like a string.

```
myObj["name"]
```

Otherwise, javascript will assume that `name` is a variable, and since you haven't created  a variable called `name`, it won't be able to access the key you're expecting.

Comment: There's still a difference between `myObj[name]` and `myObj.name` though, because the former refers to a variable name and the second to a literal key.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```js
var currentObj = {
    name: 'Umut',
    age : 34
};

var newValues = {
    name: 'Onur',
}
```

**Option 1:**

```js
currentObj = Object.assign(currentObj, newValues);
```

**Option 2:**

```js
currentObj = {...currentObj, ...newValues};
```

**Option 3:**

```js
Object.keys(newValues).forEach(key => {
    currentObj[key] = newValues[key];
});
```