# d3 - return only data without header

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a `csv` data.

**DATA :**

```
Time,Count
1377973800,293
1377975600,212
1377977400,129
1377979200,89
1377981000,54
1377982800,21
1377984600,15
```

I want to return the data in this format.

```
{
"946705035":4,
"946706692":4,
"946707210":0,
"946709243":2,
"946710714":5,
"946712907":3,
"946713183":4,
"946719001":0
}
```

I do not want the header `Time` and `Count` to be appeared in the json format.

Tried using `d3.nest()` but the result I got like it starts with `key` variable which i don't want.

Someone please help me in getting the data in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a code similar to this would do the job:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    var myObject = {};
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
        myObject[data[i].Time] = data[i].Count;
};
```

This gives you data about counts as strings, and if you want numbers, you can just add a "+", which will trigger conversion from string to number:

```
        myObject[data[i].Time] = +data[i].Count;
```

EDIT: Here is related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439915/how-to-set-a-javascript-object-values-dynamically) on creating object properties dynamically, maybe you can find something useful there too.