# Check all properties of object for undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined

I'm trying to step through an object to make sure none of the properties are undefined.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439915/how-to-set-a-javascript-object-values-dynamically) and implemented the following code, but it does not work.

```
for (var property in p.properties) {
    if (p.properties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (typeof property == 'undefined') {
            p.properties[property] = '';
            //a breakpoint here will NOT be hit
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I explicitly check the one that I know has undefined values, it does work:

```
if(typeof p.properties.st == 'undefined') {
    p.properties.st = '';
    //a breakpoint here WILL be hit
}
```

Here is how the data is obtained:

```
$.getJSON("data/stuff.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data.features, function (i, p) {
       //checking for undefined properties here
    }
});
```

Comment: you are checking to see if it is `'undefined'` as a string. Lose the quotes: `undefined`

Comment: I don't think that's right...

Comment: @mcranston18 `typeof` always returns a string.

Comment: @Barmar my mistake. Should have read the code more thoroughly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (typeof p.properties[property] == 'undefined')
```

You're testing whether the property *name* is undefined, which isn't possible; you want to test whether the *value* is undefined.

Comment: Hmm, I still get "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" when I try p.properties.st.toLowerCase()

Comment: I don't think JSON will ever create properties with undefined values. The property probably doesn't exist at all.

Comment: So why does the second code fix it but not the first (in my original post)?

Comment: The difference is that a nonexistent property will never be tested in the `for` loop, because it's getting the list of properties names from the object itself. What you need is an array containing all the property names that are supposed to exist.

Comment: ahhhhhh, that makes sense.  I probably need to create a new question.