# Add element to array like json

Tags: javascript

I get the following error on data.push. Why?

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

when doing this in javascript

```
var data = ({"name": "button", "value": "delete"});
data.push({"id": 456});

console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    type: ...
    url: ...
    data: data,
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data) {
    ...
}).fail(function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: `data[key]=value` lets you specify a key+value for objects, whereas push() only specifies a value for Arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead. Your data is an object, not an array:

```
var data = {"name": "button", "value": "delete"};
data.id = 456;
console.log(data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orf40c66/

Somewhat related: [How to set a Javascript object values dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439915/how-to-set-a-javascript-object-values-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

Actually `data` is not an array, but an object. Array must be declared inside square brackets.

```js
var data = [{"name": "button", "value": "delete"}];
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

`push` is a method for arrays, not objects