# Update values inside javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am working with the Affirm javascript API and I need to be able to update the values inside the checkout object but am having trouble doing so. I have tried what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439915/how-to-set-a-javascript-object-values-dynamically) but it isnt working.

Basically the object looks something like this:

```
affirm.checkout({  
   "merchant":{  
      "user_confirmation_url":"https://example.com/checkout/",
      "user_cancel_url":"https://example.com/exit"
   },
   "config":{  
      "financial_product_key":"XXXXXXXXX"
   },
   "shipping":{  
      "name":{  
         "full":"Blah Person"
      },
      "address":{  
         "line1":"123 example street",
         "city":"Blah",
         "state":"IL",
         "zipcode":"12345",
         "country":"US"
      }
   },
   "billing":{  
      "name":{  
         "full":"Dirty Larry"
      },
      "address":{  
         "line1":"123 blah street",
         "city":"foo",
         "state":"IL",
         "zipcode":"12345",
         "country":"US"
      }
   },
   "items":[  
      {  
         "display_name":"Example Product",
         "sku":"123",
         "unit_price":"1222",
         "qty":"1",
         "item_image_url":"https://example.com/kitty.jpg",
         "item_url":"https://example.com/product/123"
      }
   ],
   "discounts":{  
      "discount_name":{  
         "discount_amount":0
      }
   },
   "metadata":{  
      "shipping_type":"Ground"
   },
   "order_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "shipping_amount":0,
   "tax_amount":0,
   "total":67599
});
```

The above is all set on the first page load but the customer can still update items in their cart so I need to add these changes to the above object if they occur.

I have tried `affirm_checkout["shipping_amount"] = 123` that doesn't update the shipping total. Neither does `affirm_checkout.shipping_amount = 123` can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `affirm.checkout` add the object to the var `affirm_checkout`? If so, the `affirm_checkout.shipping_amount = 123` should work.

Comment: I have tried both ways and it still doesn't update. Here is the documentation https://docs.affirm.com/v2/api/affirm-js/#initialize-affirm-js

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong code? The `checkout` suggest to me this is the last stage before you go to a payment or something?

Comment: Yes you are correct. `affirm.checkout.post()` is what gets called and takes them to the affirm website

Comment: I think the checkout is already the order submission...

Comment: Seems like it has a `set` function. Try `affirm.checkout.set('shipping_amount', newamount);`.

Comment: Still no good :( I got excited there for a minute

Comment: Nevermind you were right I was updating `shipping_amount` but looking at the total. I have to update the total as well as the shipping amount. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Yamaha32088 How do access it in javaScript ?

Comment: You can access the value like affirm.checkout.get('shipping_amount') and it will return the amount to set it you do affirm.checkout.set('shipping_amount', 123)

Comment: @Yamaha32088 Is get method provided by Affirm JavaScript API or it's core JavaScript method ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the checkout object as a variable outside the context of the affirm.checkout function. This way, you can directly access the contents of the object and pass it to affirm.checkout(yourCheckoutObject);

```
var yourCheckoutObject = {}; //define default or placeholder values
yourCheckoutObject.shipping_amount = 2000; //amounts are expressed in integer USD cents
affirm.checkout(yourCheckoutObject); //pass the object to the checkout function
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
{
merchant: "foo bar",
config: "baz"
}
```

Then you can access that by

```
checkout.merchant = 123
```

Comment: OP already tried that. It's not just an object, it's an object that gets passed to a function. So accessing it is not as straight forward.