# How to Update a value after a Json Response

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript

How can i access the `BookProperties` Array(24) and update the  `Book-EngineType` with the value `SG` to something like `EngineType1`

[image]

what i expect to get within `setState()` is `Book-EngineType` to be of value `EngineType1` and not `SG`.

Comment: Duplicate? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439915/how-to-set-a-javascript-object-values-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```js
let bookProperties = [
    {name:'bookallowtostorehistory', val:'manual'},
    {name:'Book-EngineType', val:'SG'}
];

bookProperties.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.name == 'Book-EngineType') {
        el.val = 'EngineType1';
    }
})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23664466)

Comment: Um, @martin, this post does not contain any links.