# Update object from class variable using method

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

My goal is to create array of objects which have set default properties, but in some cases I will need to update one or more of property.
Here is my example class with variables - objects

```
export class Components{
    public static component_1 = {
        width: 1,
        height: 2,
        x: 3,
        y:4
    }
    
    public static component_2 = {
        width: 10,
        height: 20,
        x: 30,
        y:40
    }

    ...
}
```

I would like to create my array of object in way eg

`let myArrOfComponents = [Components.component_1, Components.component_2, ...]`

The problem is that in some cases I will have to update one or more of properties in object, eg width and x. I would like to do this for example like

```
let myArrOfComponents = [Components.component_1.configure(width = 99, x=88)]
```

Can you help me how I can do this? Im not sure how implement '.configure()' I'm trying to solve this but have no idea how implement it or something with similar behavior

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439915/how-to-set-a-javascript-object-values-dynamically

Comment: [Do not use `class` syntax for only `static` members!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)

Comment: `{...components.component_1, width: 99, x: 88}` should do. If those are actually instances, you can give them a method to clone+update them, including doing more advanced stuff. Pass an object as the argument, JS does not have named arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be to make them methods (so called "factory methods").

```
class Components {
    static component_1 = (options = null) => ({
        width: 1,
        height: 2,
        x: 3,
        y: 4,
        ...options
    })
}
```

Now, `Components.component_1()` will return a default object, and e.g. `Components.component_1({x: 25, width: 100})` a "configured" one.

Comment: It looks, great! I will try it! :)