# Add or remove a class based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am adding / removing a class from an element’s `classList` based on a variable’s truthiness. However, I’m doing it in what appears to be an obtuse way:

```js
if (myConditionIsMet) {
  myEl.classList.add("myClass");
} else {
  myEl.classList.remove("myClass");
}
```

Is there a way in which I could make this more sexy and dynamically call the `add` / `remove` chained function for example with a conditional operator such as:

```js
myEl.classList.{myConditionIsMet ? add('myClass') : remove('myClass')};
```

The above is pseudocode, of course, and I would like as plain JS as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a Javascript object values dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439915/how-to-set-a-javascript-object-values-dynamically)

Comment: The same thing with jQuery: [Neater way of checking adding/removing a CSS class using 'hasClass' in jQuery?](/q/8619466/4642212).

Comment: [How do I call a dynamically-named method in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There’s a [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method on `.classList` which takes a second argument (`force`).
This boolean argument essentially takes a condition that adds the class if true, and removes the class if false.

```js
myEl.classList.toggle("myClass", myConditionIsMet);
```

Answer (score 7):

Your pseudocode js

```js
myEl.classList.{myConditionIsMet ? add('myClass') : remove('myClass')};
```

can be translated to actual js

```js
myEl.classList[myConditionIsMet ? 'add' : 'remove']('myClass');
```

which is not particularly readable, but does exactly what you described.

For readability, I would look at the [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method.