# String concatenation not working, throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, concatenation

I am storying a dynamic string in a variable  and then resuing that string later in the code. It is throwing an error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +"

```
var template_url = "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>";

$(document).ready(function() {

    var urlCameraDic = 
          {
            template_url + '/sliders/walking.html' : 'camera_1',
            template_url + '/sliders/lobby.html' : 'camera_2',
            template_url + '/sliders/cafe.html' : 'camera_3',
            template_url + '/sliders/womens.html' : 'camera_4'
          };
});
```

I am not sure why this error is being thrown. Am I concatenating this incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot execute javascript when declaring the keys of an object by object literal.

You can do this though

```
var urlCameraDic = {};
urlCameraDic[template_url + '/sliders/walking.html'] = 'camera_1';
urlCameraDic[template_url + '/sliders/lobby.html'] = 'camera_2';
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your custom keys after creation like so:

```
var urlCameraDic = {};
urlCameraDic[template_url + '/sliders/walking.html'] = 'camera_1';
// add the other items like above
```

See [this similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708229/485048) for more details.