# Jquery Array Object - How to add suffix variable to index names

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this array object which initiates each index:

```
var example = { 'hours': 0, 'overtime': 0, 'income': 0, 'expenditure': 0 };
```

However it is inside a `.each()` loop. Each index needs a unique identifier like: `hours0` `hours1`.

The old format that I used to append a suffix is bulky.

```
example['hours'       + index] = 0;
example['overtime'    + index] = 0;
example['income'      + index] = 0;
example['expenditure' + index] = 0;
```

I've tried the following.

```
var example = { 'hours'+index: 0, 'overtime'+index: 0, 'income'+index: 0, 'expenditure'+index: 0 };
```

But it results in: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`

any ideas?

Comment: using brackets is the correct way actually

Comment: I don't think there is another way to do this, perhaps you can just define `e = example` and then `e['hours'       + index] = 0; etc...` and finally `example = e`

Comment: You have to use bracket notation - for a full explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708192/use-a-concatenated-dynamic-string-as-javascript-object-key

Comment: Thanks guys, I hear you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternate way to do this that might work for you:

```
var employee = [];

var numEmpl = 100; // total number of employees

for(var i = 0; i < numEmpl; i++)
  employee[i] = {'hours' : 0, 'overtime' : 0, 'income' : 0, 'expenditure' : 0};
```

The above code gives you an array of objects, one for each employee. Each object (employee) property can be accessed individually like this:

```
employee[20].overtime = 10;

console.log(employee[20].overtime) // => 10
```

Alternately, you can update all info for a given employee at one time like this:

```
employee[30] = {'hours' : 45, 'overtime' : 5, 'income' : 1000, 'expenditure' : 0}

console.log(employee[30].overtime) // => 5
```

To add a new employee, simply do this:

```
employee.push({'hours' : 0, 'overtime' : 0, 'income' : 0, 'expenditure' : 0})
```

Comment: This is definitely a much better way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

Add new keys and delete old keys

```
 var example = {
       'hours': 0,
       'overtime': 0,
       'income': 0,
       'expenditure': 0
   };
   var index = 0;
   for (var key in example) {
       example[key + index] = example[key];//adding new key with old value
       delete example[key];//delete old key
   }
   console.log(example);
```

**Output:** `Object {hours0: 0, overtime0: 0, income0: 0, expenditure0: 0}`

Answer (score 0):

Gerald's answer definitely is the best way to do it.

However note that it is also possible to evaluate string expressions as object fields inline. Here's how you do it:

```
let a = { ['foo' + 'bar' + 123]: 5 }
// a is now { foobar123: 5 }
```