# How to increment a value inside an object variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I have the following.

```
var dataset = {val1 : 0, val2 : 0, val3 : 0};
var person = [];
var totalPeople = 10;

for(var i = 0; i <totalPeople; i++) {
   person[i] = dataset; 
}
```

Why i chose this approach, click [here
.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663030/jquery-array-object-how-to-add-suffix-variable-to-index-names)

I'm trying to make one of the values auto increment inside another `for` loop.

I've tried the following approaches to no avail.

```
person[1]{val1 : 0,
          val2 : 0,
          val3 : val3 + 1};

person[1]{val1 : 0,
          val2 : 0,
          val3 : person[1].val3 + 1};

person[1].val3 = person[1].val3 + 1;
```

any ideas?

Comment: `person[i].val3+=1` ? Not sure what you want to do

Comment: How it is connected with jquery?

Comment: Are you trying to increment the field name, or the field value?

Comment: Juvian, I'll expand the code a little. U_mulder, I was writing with the intention of Jquery.. but this was an answer given to another question. oops if it is pure js [newby :) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally sorry. The solution that you're referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663030/jquery-array-object-how-to-add-suffix-variable-to-index-names) was posted by me and is incorrect.  I just updated my answer in that post.

Don't use the array initialization style that I originally posted:

```
var dataset = {val1 : 0, val2 : 0, val3 : 0};
var person = [];
var totalPeople = 10;

for(var i = 0; i < totalPeople; i++) {
  person[i] = dataset; // this assigns the *same* object reference to every 
                       // member of the person array.

}
```

This is the *correct* way to initialize your person array:

```
var person = [];
var totalPeople = 10;

for(var i = 0; i < totalPeople; i++) {
  person[i] = {val1 : 0, val2 : 0, val3 : 0}; // do this to create a *unique* object 
                                              // for every person array element
}
```

If you use the correct array initializtion shown directly above, then you can increment val3 like this with each loop iteration:

```
var person = [];
var totalPeople = 10;

for(var i = 0; i < totalPeople; i++) {
  person[i] = {val1 : 0, val2 : 0, val3 : 0};
  person[i]['val3'] = i;
}
```

Sorry again for the bad information that I provided in the other post. (All other info is correct. Just the array initialization code was bad.)  I hope this updated information helps.

Answer (score 7):

This should be the right:

```
person[1].val3 += 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
var dataset = {val1 : 0, val2 : 0, val3 : 0};
var person = [];
var totalPeople = 10;

for(var i = 0; i <totalPeople; i++) {
   dataset[i].val3 ++; 
}
```

Could you explain more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to do this? perhaps some ES6 magic?