# How to attach variable to another variables name?

Tags: javascript

So I have this simple condition:

```
var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
```

And I have to repeat it 5 times like this:

```
var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
var q2 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q2"].value;
var q3 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q3"].value;
var q4 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q4"].value;
var q5 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q5"].value;
```

But Instead I want to use a simple cycle like this:

```
for (n = 1; n < 5; n++) { 
        var qn = document.forms["quizForm"]["qn"].value;
    }
```

So how do I add number **n** to a variable **q**? So instead of q1 it looked something like q**n** in the cycle?

So If I use this loop:

```
function submitAnswers(){
    var total = 5;
    var score = 0;

    for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) { 
        var qn = document.forms["quizForm"]["q" + n].value;
    }

    //Validation 
    if( ! q1){
        alert('You missed question 1');
        return false;
    }

}
```

Validation doesn't trigger, like if q1 wasn't existing.

But if I do next it triggers:

```
function submitAnswers(){
    var total = 5;
    var score = 0;

    var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;

    //Validation 
    if( ! q1){
        alert('You missed question 1');
        return false;
    }

}
```

So I guess qn isn't working it's declaring `qn` as a value instead.

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) { 
        eval('var q' + n + '=document.forms['quizForm']['q' + n + '].value;');
        alert(q1);
    }
```

But no luck so far.

Comment: What about an array of values ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a concatenated (dynamic) string as JavaScript object key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708192/use-a-concatenated-dynamic-string-as-javascript-object-key)

Comment: @RGraham not exactly, it's using array positions in there, i need a variable declaration to be dynamic.

Comment: @Tachi after success what you want? You need to do score calculation only? Can you please confirm what operation will perform after success so  i will help you more.

Comment: @Mitul Yes, I only want to calculate the overall score, I'm just following some tutorial and improving some things in it with simple things like loops. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the validation inside the loop and do the score calculation in same loop.

```
var total = 5;
var score = 0;
for (i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
    if(document.forms["quizForm"]["q" + i].value == ""){
        alert("You missed question " + i);
        return false;
    } 
    score += document.forms["quizForm"]["q" + i].value;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check your invalid question inside loop

```
function submitAnswers(){
var total = 5;
var score = 0;

for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) { 
    var qn = document.forms["quizForm"]["q" + n].value;
 //Validation 
if( ! qn){
    alert('You missed question '+n);
    break;
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work.
Javascript implicitly converts types. In your case, it is enough to use + operator.

```
for (n = 1; n < 5; n++) { 
    var qn = document.forms["quizForm"]["q" + n].value;
}
```

By the way, according to your first example, your loop should look like

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
```

or it will not hit n === 5.