# How to use a variable value as a property of an object?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create an object property from a variable value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875)

I want to create an object using a value in a variable as the property name.

I have a variable called propertyName:

```
propertyName = "first";
```

How do I use the value stored in this variable as object property, as in the following?

```
obj.first = something; // 'first' should be extracted from propertyName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html#vId):

```
obj[propertyName] = something;
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
object[ propertyName ];
```

It's an alternative form to the dot notation. What sets it apart from it is that it allows you to dynamically generate the property name using strings.