# Access JavaScript Object Variable Properties

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript)

How to access property name stored in variable like this?

```
var obj = {};

obj.foo = 'bar';
var propName = 'foo';

//I want something like this:
console.debug(obj.{propName});
```

Is there any possibility to do it without using eval()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the objects properties like:

```
myObject['property_name']
```

Try:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 'bar';
var propName = 'foo';
console.log(obj[propName]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of cource you can:

```
​(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.foo = 'bar';

    var key = 'foo';

    document.write(obj[key]);
})()​
```