# Create key:value pairs for an object while looping and setting variable for each

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript)

OK - this is a tough on for me. I am looping through all of my classes="data" using jQuery. I then want to assign properties to my feature using each specific "dataName" and "dataValue". However, once complete, I only have a a propery of "dataName=(the last value looped)". How can I assign my dataName variable to create a new property each time - instead of thinking I only want to create a property named "dataValue"

```
function pushAttributesintoFeature(feature) {  
  $(".data").each( function(){
    var dataName = $(this).attr("name")
    var dataValue = $(this).val()   
    feature.dataName = dataValue
  })
}
```

Example:

```
<input class="data" name="radius" value="15">
<input class="data" name="height" value="5">
```

Once I execute the script, I am left with: `feature.dataName = "5"`
But I want: `feature.radius="15"` AND `feature.height = "5"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the square bracket syntax to access a property with a variable:

```
feature[dataName] = dataValue;
```

This will set a property whose identifier is the *value* of `dataName`, rather than the literal string "dataName".

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this:

```
feature[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sintax for setting the values:

```
function pushAttributesintoFeature(feature) {  
  $(".data").each( function(){
    var dataName = $(this).attr("name")
    var dataValue = $(this).val()   
    feature[dataName] = dataValue;
  })
}
```

Comment: "Syntax like this... is equivalent to this"... no it's not, that's the whole point! Did you miss the quotes around `dataName` in the first example? That would make them equivalent.

Comment: @James Allardice You've misunderstand my answer. But I've edited it to avoid future misuderstandings.