# How to fill a Javascript object literal with many static key/value pairs efficiently?

Tags: javascript, object-literal, static-initialization

The typical way of creating a Javascript object is the following:

```
var map = new Object();
map[myKey1] = myObj1;
map[myKey2] = myObj2;
```

I need to create such a map where both keys and values are Strings. I have a large but static set of pairs to add to the map.

Is there any way to perform something like this in Javascript:

```
var map =  { { "aaa", "rrr" }, { "bbb", "ppp" } ... };
```

or do I have to perform something like this for each entry:

```
map["aaa"]="rrr";
map["bbb"]="ppp";
...
```

Basically, remaining Javascript code will loop over this map and extract values according to criterias known 'at runtime'. If there is a better data structure for this looping job, I am interested too. My objective is to minimize code.

Comment: Did you actually try `var map =  { { "aaa", "rrr" }, { "bbb", "ppp" } ... };` as you were asking?  Because this works just fine when you put an additional key before the value... `{ key:{ "aaa", "rrr" }, key1:{ "bbb", "ppp" } }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript)

Comment: @jbabey not really a duplicate of your proposed question but I'm pretty sure this has been asked before;)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

JavaScript's object literal syntax, which is typically used to instantiate objects (seriously, no one uses `new Object` or `new Array`), is as follows:

```
var obj = {
    'key': 'value',
    'another key': 'another value',
     anUnquotedKey: 'more value!'
};
```

For arrays it's:

```
var arr = [
    'value',
    'another value',
    'even more values'
];
```

If you need objects within objects, that's fine too:

```
var obj = {
    'subObject': {
        'key': 'value'
    },
    'another object': {
         'some key': 'some value',
         'another key': 'another value',
         'an array': [ 'this', 'is', 'ok', 'as', 'well' ]
    }
}
```

This convenient method of being able to instantiate static data is what led to the [JSON data format](http://www.json.org/).

JSON is a little more picky, keys must be enclosed in double-quotes, as well as string values:

```
{"foo":"bar", "keyWithIntegerValue":123}
```

Answer (score 171):

In ES2015 a.k.a ES6 version of JavaScript, a new datatype called `Map` is introduced.

```
let map = new Map([["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]]);
map.get("key1"); // => value1
```

check [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Relation_with_Array_objects) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

It works fine with the object literal notation:

```
var map = { key : { "aaa", "rrr" }, 
            key2: { "bbb", "ppp" } // trailing comma leads to syntax error in IE!
          }
```

Btw, the common way to instantiate arrays

```
var array = [];
// directly with values:
var array = [ "val1", "val2", 3 /*numbers may be unquoted*/, 5, "val5" ];
```

and objects

```
var object = {};
```

Also you can do either:

```
obj.property     // this is prefered but you can also do
obj["property"]  // this is the way to go when you have the keyname stored in a var

var key = "property";
obj[key] // is the same like obj.property
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
var map = {"aaa": "rrr", "bbb": "ppp"};
```

Comment: this is an object named map, not a map

Answer (score 1):

Try this typescript

```
const MAP: Record<string, string> = {
  key1: 'value1'
};

MAP[this.name]
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you wrote as first is not valid. You can achieve something using the follow:

```
var map =  {"aaa": "rrr", "bbb": "ppp" /* etc */ };
```