# Right way to declare a static Javascript map with String keys and String values

Tags: javascript, string, dictionary, static

Is this the right way to declare a static Javascript map of String keys and String values?

```
var myMap = {
    "key 1" : "value 1", 
    "key 2" : "value 2", 
    ...
    "key n" : "value n"
};
```

**REM:** all keys and values will be html escaped for special characters, they may contain blank spaces.

Comment: looks correct to me.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. 11 more characters to go.

Comment: close duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711956/how-to-fill-a-javascript-map-with-many-static-key-value-pairs-efficiently?rq=1

Comment: Sorry, the answer to this question is already available in another of my questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711956/how-to-fill-a-javascript-map-with-many-static-key-value-pairs-efficiently?rq=1. Still need to finish my morning coffee lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the normal and correct way to initialize a Javascript object.

Comment: you should be voting for a close, not providing a one line answer to a  non-question.

Comment: This is not really a question

Comment: Prasath, how is this not a real question? Where do you get that from SO guidelines and FAQs?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the right way to declare a static Javascript map of String keys and String values?

That's a fine [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), yes. Though, there is nothing really "static" in JavaScript (only the scope of the `myMap` variable which you declared with [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), but not it's value).

> all keys and values will be html escaped for special characters

That sounds unnecessary, unless you expect the strings to be written into html markup (and there are better ways). If you just escaped them since the script is included in a html document, it was useless - the only thing that needs to be escaped in *inline* scripts is the sequence `</script>`. You just have to string-escape them (i.e. escape backslashes and quotes).

Comment: How? If you properly use `document.createTextNode`, you don't need to escape them. Only if you do something like `"<div>"+key+myMap[key]+"</div>"` you need to worry about escaping (and injections).