# Accessing concatenated property names without the use of eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I would like to figure out how to concatenate an object in a for loop; eval() works fine, but I would like optimum efficiency and much of what I have searched on Google leads me to believe eval() is not a safe choice. I have looked at other examples that relate to eval(), however, none seem to be the same case.

I'm a beginner with Javascript, so apologies if this has an easy resolution.

```
objFunction: function () {
        var concat1;
        var concat2;
        $('table tbody tr').each(function (i) {
            i++;
            for (var x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {                   
                concat1 = 'obj1.obj2.obj3.step' + i + '[' + x + ']' + '.name';
                concat2 = 'obj1.obj2.obj3.step' + i + '[' + x + ']' + '.icon';

                console.log(eval(concat1));
                console.log(eval(concat2));
});
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not clear why `obj1.obj2.obj3["step"+i][x].name` is not sufficient. Also, I'm afraid I'm not clear on what your code is actually supposed to do.

Comment: do you want to concatenate `strings` or merge `objects`?

Comment: apsillers is right, your code is equivalent to what (s)he wrote.

Comment: Related: [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2241875/710446)

Comment: @YD1m my goal was to merge objects, sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're already using the [bracket notation member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). Just use it for the `stepN` as well:

```
function () {
    $('table tbody tr').each(function (i) {
        i++;
        for (var x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
            console.log(obj1.obj2.obj3['step'+i][x].name);
            console.log(obj1.obj2.obj3['step'+i][x].icon);
        } // <-- you're missing this brace, btw
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I only used the brackets to access the elements inside the array, I didn't know you could use it for that as well, thanks!~

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
concat1 = 'obj1.obj2.obj3.step' + i + '[' + x + ']' + '.name';
concat2 = 'obj1.obj2.obj3.step' + i + '[' + x + ']' + '.icon';
console.log(eval(concat1));
console.log(eval(concat2));
```

You can use:

```
console.log(obj1.obj2.obj3['step' + i][x].name);
console.log(obj1.obj2.obj3['step' + i][x].icon);
```

That would have the same effect. `obj1.obj2` is the same as `obj1['obj2']`. That's just a different notation.

Also your `for` seems to be missing its closing curly bracket (`}`).

Answer (score 0):

Does this not do what you want?

```
objFunction: function () {
    var concat1;
    var concat2;
    $('table tbody tr').each(function (i) {
        i++;
        for (var x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {                   
            console.log(obj1.obj2.obj3['step' + i][x].name);
            console.log(obj1.obj2.obj3['step' + i][x].icon);
    });
}
```

I haven't tested this out, but it should be pretty close to what you require. Try experimenting with the syntax a bit and splitting out pieces of the nesting into sub-expressions assigned to other variables to figure out where it's going wrong, if it's not working right off the bat.