# Jquery AJAX function - how can I use a variable for JSON?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to be able to supply the JSON variable name and its value via variables, instead of hard-coding it:

```
data: {
  inputVar : inputVal
},
```

but doing it like that and defining

```
inputVar = 'myInputVar';
```

doesn't work, instead entering the POST variable name directly only works:

```
'myInputVar' : inputVal
```

In the end, what I'd like to accomplish is to create a function that allows me to just call it to make an AJAX call in the JSON format, by supplying the JSON formatted AJAX variable and value in the function call:

```
makeAjaxJsonCall(fileName, postVar, postVal) {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : fileName,
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {
      inputVar : inputVal
    },
    success : function(data) {
      .
      .
      .
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      .
      .
      .
    }
  });
}
```

Any ideas?

PS. I really don't know too much about JavaScript programming, so please be precise with full code when replying - thanks!

Comment: use `JSON.stringify()` https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/core-javascript-reference/json-stringify

Comment: duplicate of [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want something like this?:

```
makeAjaxJsonCall(fileName, postVar, postVal) {
  var data = {};
  data[postVar] = postVal;
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : fileName,
    dataType : 'json',
    data: data,
    success : function(data) {
      .
      .
      .
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      .
      .
      .
    }
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can set object values like this.

```
var obj = {};

//This is the same as...
obj.value1 = 'one';

//This...
var varName = 'value1'
obj[varName] = 'one';
```

Answer (score 0):

A small explanation of the last two answers:

You can define elements of an object in this way:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.element = 1;
// And using a variable just like you want:
var key = 'myKey';
myObj[key] = 2;

console.log(myObj.key); // 2
```

So, you can build your data object first, and then pass it to the ajax hash:

```
// ...

var myData = {};
myData[inputVal] = 'my value';

//...

makeAjaxJsonCall(fileName, postVar, postVal) {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : fileName,
    dataType : 'json',
    data: myData, // <-------------
    success : function(data) {

// ...
```

Hope this helps.
Regards.