# Why is node.js complaining about my array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm receiving this error when I try to start node:

```
console.dir({socket.id:data});
                   ^
```

Why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using JSON to describe an object, the key names must directly translate to a string literal (as in, not refer to other variable identifiers). If you want another object's value to be the key name of the variable, you may try this:

```
var o = {};
o[socket.id] = data;
console.dir(o);
```

Comment: This is what I did in the end. But it seemed like unnecessary writing for a simple task.

Comment: It just happens to be part of the JavaScript syntax. Whether declaring an object in JSON format (`{something: 1}`) or using dot notation (`o.something = 1`), key names are interpreted as strings directly, converted from other types if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `.` in object key's names. If you really want to do this, use

```
{ 'socket.id' : data }
```

Comment: socket.id is a variable, if I do `` it won't be variable but a string.