# How to create array with variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an svg map with several points where I want to store the initial position of each point in an array. And each point has it's own ID, like point_1, point_2 etc.

I have attached a click handler to each of these and run a function when they are clicked.
So what I want to do in this function is to check if the array already contains the information of the clicked element. If it doesn't, I want to create it.

This is what I want to do, in pseudo code

```
var arrPoints = [];

zoomToPoint('point_1');

function zoomToPoint(data_id) {
   // Does array already contain the data?
   if (!arrPoints.data_id) {
      // Add data to the array
      arrPoints.data_id.clientX = somevalue;
      arrPoints.data_id.clientY = somevalue;
   }
}
```

This would basically create an array that looks like this:

```
arrPoints.point_1[]
arrPoints.point_2[]
```

Where I can access the data in each .point_1 and .point_2.
But I can't create an array based on a variable, like this:

```
arrPoints.data_id = [];
```

Because I end up with data_id as the actual name, not the variable that data_id actually is. So how is this usually accomplished? How can I identify each point to the actual array?
Sorry for my lack of basics

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create object property from variable value in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Running through a JS tutorial real quick might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an object:

```
var arrPoints = {};

zoomToPoint('point_1');

function zoomToPoint(data_id) {
    // Does array already contain the data?
    if (!arrPoints[data_id]) {  // square brackets to use `data_id` as index
        // Add data to the array
        arrPoints[data_id] = {};
        arrPoints[data_id].clientX = somevalue;
        arrPoints[data_id].clientY = somevalue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, I had to pass the variable in '[]', that was basically the only thing I was missing.

Comment: Yea, pretty much :-) Also notice how `arrPoints` is an Object instead of an array, @KennyBones.