# Create Arrays in JavaScript like in PHP

Tags: javascript

can I use following (PHP) Syntax to create an array in JavaScript?

```
$arr = ("foo" => "bar", "foobar" => "test");
```

I dont want to use following syntax (in JS):

```
var arr = [];
arr["foo"] = "bar";
arr["foobar"] = "test";
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Those aren't arrays, those are objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = {foo:"bar", foobar:"test"};

var foo = arr.foo;
var foobar = arr.foobar;
```

Comment: You really shouldn't answer questions as basic as this one. Stack Overflow is not a JS api.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I dont use objecs, is, that I cant use a variable as a key. Array: arr[key] (key is a variable).

Comment: @Tream The first thing that comes into mind is that you can use `eval()` vor variables: `eval('arr.' + key)`

Comment: Dude, no. Don't ever use `eval`. Especially not like that! Use `arr[key]` instead.

Comment: You can also use arr[key] for objects. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript

Comment: Arrays are objects in JavaScript. If you can access `arr[key]` in an array then you can do the same with an object. (There are no "associative arrays" in JavaScript.)