# Using a parameter as a property

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function which loops out options for two different selects, using parameters to tell the function which array of items it should use. The problem comes when I try to convert the parameter to "plain text" so that I can use it as a property of the `calendarModel`. If I use dot notation it tries to access a property called `category` in `calendarModel` which obviously doesn't work.

After looking at this question: [How to create an object property from a variable value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-object-property-from-variable-value-in-javascript) I thought that my solution would work, but the problem in that question isn't exactly like mine so I must've misunderstood it or something.

Right now I only get  **1 option** and it's **undefined**. When it really should be as many as items in `years` and `months` as well as having the values. Where am I going wrong here?

```
var calendarModel = {
    months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
         'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
        ],
    years: ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '2024']
}

(function() {

var selectMonth = document.getElementById('month');
var selectYear = document.getElementById('year');

function createOptions(category, element) {

        for (i = 0; i < calendarModel[category].length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.innerHTML = calendarModel[category[i]];
                option.value = option.innerHTML;
                element.appendChild(option);
        }
    }

    createOptions('years', selectYear);
    createOptions('months', selectMonth);;
}())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a bit mixed up. `category` is just a string, so you're passing in `y` (years) into `calendarModel`

I think you want to use the loop index on the outside.

```
option.innerHTML = calendarModel[category][i]; //notice [i] is not the index of the category string anymore
```

Comment: That fixed the innerHTML problem but I still only get 1 option, how would I use it in the for loop expression?

Comment: nvm found the problem, there was a left over z-index in my css that prevented me from seeing the rest..

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the following line:

`option.innerHTML = calendarModel[category[i]];`

This is going to try and look for property `i` on category, which is just a string. This is why you are getting undefined.

Instead, you should be doing the following:

`option.innerHTML = calendarModel[category][i];`

This will find the corresponding values to your `category` property on `calendarModel`

Comment: Ye I fixed that, but I still only get one option because it can't find a length of calendarModel[category]. Do I need to add brackets there or something?

Comment: nvm found the problem, there was a left over z-index in my css that prevented me from seeing the rest..