# How to define object key using other object property value?

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I want to use object property value as key (simplified):

```
var App = function() {
    this.settings = {
        'tetris': {
            title: 'Tetris'
        },
        'galaxian': {
            title: 'Galaxian'
        }
    };
    this.gameName = 'tetris';
    this.request = {
        this.settings[this.gameName].title: 'THIS KEY IS INVALID' // :(
    }
};
```

I know I could **assign** it as:

```
this.request[ this.settings[this.gameName].title ] = 'Valid...';
```

But I wonder if I can **define** the property name using the object property value?

Comment: The answers below are correct - you can't define properties in this way.  At least, [not until ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25333702/791010).

Comment: Yes, I hoped I was wrong, will have to assign.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid, what you mean is not possible. You can **not** use a variable as a key in an object literal like this:

```
var key = "somekey";
var obj = {key: "value"}
```

The above code will result in an object that has the key `key`.

You can only use a variable to define an object element like this:

```
var key = "somekey";
var obj = {};
obj[key] = "value"
```

Then the object get's an element with the key `somekey`

EDIT: As stated in the comments, in ECMAScript 6 the support for computed properties in object literals got introduced. However the browser support for the computed properties in object literals is very slim (you can look it up [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) under syntax -> object literals). For example IE 11 has no support for it, neither has Chrome 43.

Comment: Not possible? Only until support for [*computed property names*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in [*ECMA-262 ed 6*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer) is sufficiently widespread. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Well I'd guess, that around at least 90 % of user browsers do not support it yet, therefore I would say it is not "possible" yet ;)

Answer (score 5):

Computed property names will be introduced in ECMAScript edition 6, they're in the [current draft](https://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer), so you can do:

```
this.request = {
    [this.settings[this.gameName].title]
}
```

They're reasonably well supported now, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for more detail.

Comment: It says it is supported only by Firefox. Good to know it will come one day. Thanks man. Actually I tried with normal brackets, of course without success.

Comment: Computed property names are supported in Safari 7.1.3

Comment: heh, Safari died man, it is not supported even by apple for PCs.

Comment: @skobaljic—a group of 70+ health clubs I'm working on a web site for get nearly 50% of their traffic from Safari on mobile. Yeah, dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define literal objects with computed property names; you have to assign them.

In other words, you can either define a literal object using `{...}` notation if the property name is well-known, or assign values into keys in a map using `x[prop] = v` notation if the property name is computed.

Think of your JS objects as being either objects or maps, but not both. If the JS object has well-known property names then it's acting as an object:

```
var obj = { 
  wellKnownPropertyName = 'value';
};

var value = obj.wellKnownPropertyName;
```

But if the property name is computed then it's not really a property of an object but more like a key in a map, and should be assigned (and read) as such:

```
var map = {};
var key = getUnknownKeyFromSomewhere();
map[key] = 'value';

var value = map[key];
```

Comment: Both answers are correct, shall mark 1st as correct only because it was first. Thank you