# Angulajs how to create object array from 2 different string and numeral array?

Tags: angularjs

how to create object array from 2 different string and numeral array in angularJS?
For example:

```
$scope.array1=['sale1','sale2','sale3']
$scope.array2=[2,3,4]
```

From these 2 arrays I want to make one array as

```
$scope.resultArray=[
                    {'key':'sale1','value':2},
                    {'key':'sale2','value':3},
                    {'key':'sale3','value':4}
                  ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-an-object-property-from-a-variable-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.array1.length; i++) {
   $scope.resultArray.push({
     'key': $scope.array1[i],
     'value': $scope.array2[i]
   });
 }
```

A *snippet* working:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.array1 = ['sale1', 'sale2', 'sale3'];
      $scope.array2 = [2, 3, 4];
      $scope.resultArray = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.array1.length; i++) {
        $scope.resultArray.push({
          'key': $scope.array1[i],
          'value': $scope.array2[i]
        });
      }
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="obj in resultArray track by $index">
    <span ng-bind="obj.key + ' - ' + obj.value"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Underscore [zip](http://underscorejs.org/#zip)

```
$scope.array1=['sale1','sale2','sale3']
$scope.array2=[2,3,4]
$scope.resultArray = _.zip($scope.array1, $scope.array2)
```

Comment: Did you change the question?

Comment: Yes he changed the quastion,after I answered

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i=0;$scope.array1.length>i;i++){
     $scope.resultArray.push({$scope.array1[i]:$scope.array2[i]});

}
```