# Random variable in key value pairs not interpreted as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some values i am trying to store in local storage using `key:value` pairs. I want the `key` to be a random value from `Math.random()` but my value is not being seen as a variable

This is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ps4xs60x/27/

and the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function(){
 var num = Math.random();
         $('.table tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>one</td><td><button id="'+num+'" onClick="ae(this.id); function ae(clicked_id) {var items = []; var entry = {\'num\': clicked_id}; items.push(entry);localStorage.setItem(\'entry\',JSON.stringify(items));alert(localStorage.getItem(\'entry\',JSON.stringify(items)));}" type="button" class="invite ">Invite</button></td></tr>');
      });
});
```

How can i make `num` to be seen as a variable?

Comment: Why do you assume, num isnt seen as a variable? Your code works absolutely fine in that aspect.

Comment: @Syntac I am expecting a number not `"num"`

Comment: @charlietfl A decimal would be fine too.

Comment: Yes, but than you would have to write `'+num+'` instead of  `\'num\'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-an-object-property-from-a-variable-value-in-javascript

Comment: Stop putting all that business logic into your html. Use jQuery event handlers to do it instead since you are using jQuery. Inline onClick is 1990's...this is 2016

Comment: @charlietfl I am not allowed jquery beyond the point i have used in the code, simply doesn't work. I am boxed into using `onClick`,nothing i can do.

Comment: then put the business logic into functions that are maintainable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Disclaimer:

So localStorage doesn't work so much in these snippets but see the code below or [this forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/of6LjgLj/).

## Code changes

1. Move the function `ae()` out of the `onClick` attribute and define it as a regular JS function.
2. Presuming you want to *add* each number clicked to the localStorage element `entry` array, then you need to parse that as json (if it is set) each time instead of making a new array.
3. Instead of using the `onclick` attribute, add a click handler for the elements with class name `invite`, just like you are doing for the elements with class name `btn-primary`...

```js
function ae(event) {
  var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('entry'));
  if (items == null || typeof items !== 'object') {
      items = [];
  }
  var entry = {
    'num': event.target.id
  };
  items.push(entry);
  localStorage.setItem('entry', JSON.stringify(items));
  alert(localStorage.getItem('entry'));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.invite', ae);
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function() {
    var num = Math.random();
    $('.table tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>one</td><td><button id="' + num + '"type="button" class="invite ">Invite</button></td></tr>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn-primary">Add Row
</button>
```