# Creating object property from a variable name

Tags: javascript

given this example:

```
var obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
};
```

will be `a:1, b:2` as excected. But what if I have:

```
var b = 'myProperty';
var obj = {
    'a': 1,
    b: 2
};
```

I wanted to have `a: 1, myProperty: 2` but I still got `a: 1, b: 2`! How to fix it?

Comment: Check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-an-object-property-from-a-variable-value-in-javascript

Comment: Please use the search: [`[javascript] object literal variable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+object+literal+variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

Variables in object property names are only allowed using the bracket notation:

```
var b = 'myProperty';

var obj = {
    'a': 1
};

obj[b] = 2;

console.log(obj.myProperty); // logs 2
```

Comment: but can it be done in one-line form?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

```js
var b = 'myProperty';
var obj = {
    'a': 1
};
obj[b]=2;
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: but can it be done in one-line form?