# Looping array data into object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I tried to loop array element into the object. I tried the given method but i got some errors in it. Loop object keys and their values based on the array.

```
let headings = ['sam', 'ram', 'ham'.....];
let dataHeading = ['headingOne', 'headingTwo', 'headingThree'....];
let data = ['one', 'two', 'three'.....];

let finaldata;
for(let i=0; i<headings.length; i++){
  finaldata = {
    heading[i]: {
      dataHeading[i] : data[i]
    }
  }
}

console.log(finaldata);


//what i want as a output is

{
  sam: {
    headingOne: one
  },
  ram: {
    headingTwo: two
  },
  ham: {
    headingThree : three
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the error messages you get to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need an assignment to the wanted property and take a [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for the object.

```js
let headings = ['sam', 'ram', 'ham'],
    dataHeading = ['headingOne', 'headingTwo', 'headingThree'],
    data = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    finaldata = {};

for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
    finaldata[headings[i]] = { [dataHeading[i]]: data[i] };
}

console.log(finaldata);
```

Comment: @SebastianThomas, i am a real person with too much time ...

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, supposing that `headings`, `dataHeading` and `data` have the same length you could do:

```js
let headings = ['sam', 'ram', 'ham'];
let dataHeading = ['headingOne', 'headingTwo', 'headingThree'];
let data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
let finaldata = {};
for(let i=0 ; i<headings.length;i++) {
   finaldata[headings[i]] = {};
   finaldata[headings[i]][dataHeading[i]] = data[i];
}
console.log(finaldata);
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic property name, you could wrap it arround square bracket `[]`

```js
let headings = ['sam', 'ram', 'ham']
let dataHeading = ['headingOne', 'headingTwo', 'headingThree']
let data = ['one', 'two', 'three']

let finaldata = {}
for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
  Object.assign(finaldata, {
    [headings[i]]: {
      [dataHeading[i]]: data[i]
    }
  })
}

console.log(finaldata)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 3 mistakes in your code:

1. A `heading[i]` typo which can be ignored as it was not a big fault.
2. You were creating object property on the fly so you should use `[]` notation. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-an-object-property-from-a-variable-value-in-javascript)
3. You were changing `finaldata` in each iteration

```
finaldata = {

heading[i] : { 
dataHeading[i] : data[i]
}
}
```

Because of this only last element i.e `ham` would be stored with with `"headingThree": "three"` i.e `{ham:{"headingThree": "three"}}` if step 2 was followed

```js
let headings = ['sam', 'ram', 'ham'];
let dataHeading = ['headingOne', 'headingTwo', 'headingThree'];
let data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

let finaldata = {};
for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {

  finaldata[headings[i]] = {
    [dataHeading[i]]: data[i]
  }
}
console.log(finaldata)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to zip all the arrays together first to get a 2d array which looks like:

```
[['sam', 'headingOne', 'one'], ['ram', 'headingTwo', 'two'], ...]
```

Once you've done that you can then map over each zipped array and use [`.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to build your nested object. This will transform the above array into an array of objects:

```
[
  {'sam': {'headingOne': 'one'}}, 
  {'ram': {'headingTwo', 'two'}},  
  ...
]
```

Lastly, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge all the objects from your array into a resulting object:

```
{
  'sam': {'headingOne': 'one'}, 
  'ram': {'headingTwo', 'two'},  
  ...
}
```

See example below:

```js
let headings = ['sam', 'ram', 'ham']
let dataHeading = ['headingOne', 'headingTwo', 'headingThree'];
let data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const zip = (...arrs) => arrs[0].map((_, i) => arrs.map(arr => arr[i]))
const makeNestedObj = arr => arr.reduceRight((obj, k) => ({[k]: obj}));

const arrObjs = zip(headings, dataHeading, data).map(makeNestedObj);
const res = Object.assign({}, ...arrObjs);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myObject = {},
    countryList = ["United Kingdom", "France"],
    marketList = ["primary", "secondary", "service"],
    data = ["one","two","three"],
    i, p;

for (var i = 0; i < countryList.length; i++) {
    myObject[countryList[i]] = {};
    for (p = 0; p < marketList.length; p++) {
        myObject[countryList[i]][marketList[p]] = data[p];
    }
}

console.log(myObject);
```