# How to create a `new` constructor for a `type`

Tags: typescript, constructor, prototype, type-alias

Is there a way to create a constructor for a `type` that aliases a native object?

I currently have a defined type which should be constructed with a default value. It will be created in many places so I want to ensure it is created consistently.

```
export enum Category { a='a', e='e', i='i', o='o', u='u' };

export type CategorisedItems = { [category in Category]: string[] };

export function createCategorisedItems(): CategorisedItems {
  return Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(Category).map(category => ({[category]: []})));
}
// {
//   a: [],
//   e: [],
//   i: [],
//   o: [],
//   u: []
// }
```

And I can create this in other objects with:

```
import { CategorisedItems, createCategorisedItems } from './categories';

export class PendingData {
  public readonly categorisedItems: CategorisedItems = createCategorisedItems();
}
```

But I would love to be able to use the `new` syntax instead.

```
import { CategorisedItems } from './categories';

export class PendingData {
  public readonly categorisedItems: CategorisedItems = new CategorisedItems();
}
```

Is this possible or just wishful thinking?

Comment: `Object.keys` on that enum is going to be `'a', 0, 'b', 1` etc. And that mapping with `Object.assign` is just going to give `{ category: [] }`. As for your actual question "Is this possible" yes. You can write a class that has explicit a, e, i, o, u properties initialized to empty `string[]`. But I'm guessing that's not what you want. Something like `class CategorizedItems { [Category.a]: string[] = [] }` and so on

Comment: I don't think that `createCategorisedItems()` function does what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks! I've edit my question and tested it creates the correct CategorisedItems object.

Comment: The function creates an object of the form `{ "category": [] } `, which does not seem to correspond to your `CategorisedItems` type. In fact, your `CategorisedItems` type has properties `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, but I also doubt that was what you intended. Question is unclear.

Comment: Yup, I've been working in Python for too long. Edited to fix that above.

Comment: @JaredSmith, that's looking like the easiest solution, so long as Category doesn't change much down the track (trying to declare things in one place only.) I forget that in JS you can refer to attributes with both dot syntax and index syntax.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food that isn't actually the index syntax in this case, it's [computed property notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25333702/3757232).

Answer (score 3):

careful with enums, check out what they transpile to:

```
var Category;
(function (Category) {
    Category[Category["a"] = 0] = "a";
    Category[Category["e"] = 1] = "e";
    Category[Category["i"] = 2] = "i";
    Category[Category["o"] = 3] = "o";
    Category[Category["u"] = 4] = "u";
})(Category || (Category = {}));

// or short:
var Category = {0: 'a', 1: 'e', 2: 'i', 3: 'o', 4: 'u', a: 0, e: 1, i: 2, o: 3, u: 4}
```

I'd use a union type:

```js
// the materialized keys (types don't exist at runtime).
const categoryKeys = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"] as const;
// and something for the typing
export type Category = typeof categoryKeys[number]; 
// => type Category = "a" | "e" | "i" | "o" | "u"
```

---

And to your main question, how to turn `createCategorisedItems()` into a Class. Basically, what we'd want is this:

```js
class CategorisedItems {
    [category in Category]: string[];

    constructor() {
        for (const key of categoryKeys) {
            this[key] = [];
        }
    }
}
```

But when declaring the class with the mapped properties, TS is nagging that the properties may not be implemented on the one hand, yet it doesn't let me implement them because they are not defined ... :(

JS and some casts to the rescue:

```js
const categoryKeys = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"] as const;

export type Category = typeof categoryKeys[number];

export type CategorisedItems = { [category in Category]: string[]; }

// a good ol JS constructor function, ...
export const CategorisedItems = function (this: CategorisedItems) {
    if (!new.target) {
        throw new Error(`Constructor CategorisedItems cannot be invoked without 'new'`);
    }

    for (const key of categoryKeys) {
        this[key] = [];
    }
    // ... but we need to nudge TS into the right direction.
} as unknown as new () => CategorisedItems
```

and a link to a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGUCmBzEAnAngaSZiMAvDANoBE8ZANDGUtbQJYNkgsCuZAujPAaJCgBuAFAikADwAOGWFExSkMAMKJUGTERjzFIAGZw1aLLnwkw7ALYAjJOi6iROpauTHGEJABMAksksExADepAhuGjCMYCpGGlwAXDDQ6FEoJA4wAL5iAPQ5vDBoIF4wIAA2MABSAMpw4MnswFAYMHrsYE2M4DQAdH3i0rJ1gjHhKZ6+-oGt7Z3gMAAUUAAWHomu6uPefkgBAJQwQSIwJ5EGCwCEYEgA7j1Q8OgoSFAHR6cf2svoIDcw138AKLoH7oBYAA2U9Sg6EazXQo02Hm2U0MYDAIFgtkiYAAbiAANbeGA3RgrEDsWAAcgBVPBe1EH2yx1OehaCwE0BgRM0+kMYxweAgbxZny+HhIPJ4xHSjNO2Q+eRgfR6MGslJJSmuxOa-3YXmeMAAKrUorqVkoUihlrAvIx0Eg5mAeiJMrwCO0CRibtE+P9bosDoQAHyI9wTHYBERAA)

---

> That's a cool thing to learn. The side effect of this is I can no longer use CategorisedItems as a type in the PendingData class or anywhere else. "'CategorisedItems' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof CategorisedItems'?"

I forgot to `export type CategorisedItems = ...;` that should fix that.

Or you could hide this as an implementation detail behind a derived class that you export:

```js
const categoryKeys = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"] as const;

export type Category = typeof categoryKeys[number];

type CategorisedItemsBase = { [category in Category]: string[]; }

const CategorisedItemsBase = function (this: CategorisedItemsBase) {
    for (const key of categoryKeys) {
        this[key] = [];
    }
} as unknown as new () => CategorisedItemsBase

// and then:
export class CategorisedItems extends CategorisedItemsBase { }
```

this also makes it simpler to build upon that base function whose sole purpose is to instantiate the mapped properties; you can go back to the nicer `class` syntax and don't have to do `CategorisedItemsBase.prototype.xyz = ...`

Comment: That's a cool thing to learn. The side effect of this is I can no longer use CategorisedItems as a type in the PendingData class or anywhere else. "'CategorisedItems' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof CategorisedItems'?"

Comment: @Hand-E-Food I forgot to `export type CategorisedItems = ...;` that should fix that.

Comment: Exporting the type works. I'm surprised you can export and import two entities with the same name. I'm guessing it's because one is a type and the other is a value?