# JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?

Tags: javascript, syntax, object-literal

Other than the obvious fact that the first form could use a variable and not just a string literal, is there any reason to use one over the other, and if so under which cases?

In code:

```
// Given:
var foo = {'bar': 'baz'};

// Then
var x = foo['bar'];

// vs. 
var x = foo.bar;
```

Context: I've written a code generator which produces these expressions and I'm wondering which is preferable.

Comment: Just to chip in, not an answer to your original question (since you've had plenty of good explanations so far), but speed-wise there's no difference worth mentioning either: http://jsperf.com/dot-vs-square-brackets. The above test gives only a 2% margin at best to either of them, they're neck and neck.

Comment: See also [How do I add a property to an object using a variable as the name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/695050/1048572) and [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/1048572)

Comment: This question/answer  can be used also for UTF-8 keys.

Answer (score 507, accepted):

(Sourced from [here](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).)

**Square bracket notation allows the use of characters that can't be used with dot notation:**

> ```
> var foo = myForm.foo[]; // incorrect syntax
> var foo = myForm["foo[]"]; // correct syntax
> ```

including non-ASCII (UTF-8) characters, as in `myForm["ダ"]` ([more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30929233/287948)).

**Secondly, square bracket notation is useful when dealing with
 property names which vary in a predictable way:**

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>   someFunction(myForm["myControlNumber" + i]);
> }
> ```

**Roundup:**

> - Dot notation is faster to write and clearer to read.
> - Square bracket notation allows access to properties containing
>     special characters and selection of
>     properties using variables

---

Another example of characters that can't be used with dot notation is *property names that themselves contain a dot*.

For example a json response could contain a property called `bar.Baz`.

```
var foo = myResponse.bar.Baz; // incorrect syntax
var foo = myResponse["bar.Baz"]; // correct syntax
```

Comment: The code examples and wording of the summary look awfully familiar. https://web.archive.org/web/20160304205521/http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/

Comment: No need in re-inventing the wheel, is there? Citing it as a reference.

Comment: Dot notation is faster (for me at least) test your browser http://jsperf.com/dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation/2

Comment: What does this mean... *The second advantage of square bracket notation is when dealing with variable property names.*? So we can use custom variable `myControlNumber` or `i` for `myForm["myControlNumber" + i]`?

Comment: Also, `[]` can resolve an otherwise ambiguous parse (without the need for `()` *as well as* `.`) - consider `obj1.obj2.foo = bar` vs. `obj1[ obj2.foo ] = bar`

Comment: Great example. I've used bracket notation a lot , and was not sure of the true purpose over dot notation. Now with this example it is clear to see the big picture.

Comment: in chrome 44 on my machine bracket notation is faster

Comment: That said, using periods and square brackets in a property is just... Yikes.

Comment: @chenghuayang That is a little confusing, isn't it? It means property names that vary. So in the example the object `myForm` is assumed to have ten properties, called `myForm.myControlNumber0...myForm.myControlNumber9`, each of which is acted on by `someFunction`. Rather than go through them one at a time, a line of code per property, they can be looped over because their names vary from each other in a predictable way.

Comment: @chenghuayang When you want to access a property of an object who's key is stored in a variable, you can't with dot notation.

Comment: dot notation makes debugging easier as you can hover over the property  to see the value while with bracket notation debugger cant evaluate it on hover.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to use bracket notation if accessing properties programmatically (variables) and use dot notation when I'm typing in known or expected property names.

Comment: On Firefox 56 there are almost the same.

Comment: Guys,I get it. The problem is I need to access a parameter that comes from the back-end. So I did this `<pre>{{ Ctrl.api.["something.else'] | json</pre>. The else has a name property. How do I access that...?

Comment: Link is broken. Do you have another source, or should the link be removed ?  (PS thanks for including *information* from the link.  This is a perfect example to those who post "link-only" answers, as to why such answers are discouraged, and should be deleted/removed, OR updated to *include* the relevant info.) I also appreciate that you cited your reference !! :-) References are super helpful for following up and additional research, when necessary.

Comment: But we can mix to dot notation and square bracket notation.

Comment: Here is the original article. https://web.archive.org/web/20121025105903/http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/index.html

Comment: Another reason: brackets notation can make your code be minified more effectively.

Answer (score 134):

The bracket notation allows you to access properties by name stored in a variable:

```
var obj = { "abc" : "hello" };
var x = "abc";
var y = obj[x];
console.log(y); //output - hello
```

`obj.x` would not work in this case.

Answer (score 25):

The two most common ways to access properties in JavaScript are with a dot and with square brackets. Both `value.x` and `value[x]` access a property on value—but not necessarily the same property. **The difference is in how x is interpreted. When using a dot, the part after the dot must be a valid variable name, and it directly names the property. When using square brackets, the expression between the brackets is evaluated to get the property name. Whereas value.x fetches the property of value named “x”, value[x] tries to evaluate the expression x and uses the result as the property name.**

So if you know that the property you are interested in is called “length”, you say `value.length`. If you want to extract the property named by the value held in the variable `i`, you say `value[i]`. And because property names can be any string, if you want to access a property named `“2”` or `“John Doe”`, you must use square brackets: `value[2]` or `value["John Doe"]`. This is the case even though you know the precise name of the property in advance, because neither `“2”` nor `“John Doe”` is a valid variable name and so cannot be accessed through dot notation.

***In case of Arrays***

The elements in an array are stored in properties. Because the names of these properties are numbers and we often need to get their name from a variable, we have to use the bracket syntax to access them. **The length property of an array tells us how many elements it contains. This property name is a valid variable name, and we know its name in advance, so to find the length of an array, you typically write `array.length` because that is easier to write than `array["length"]`.**

Comment: Could you elaborate more on array.length? You say that properties accessed by dot notation are not evaluated so in case of array.length wouldn't it give us "length" string instead of evaluated value, in this case the number of items in array? `The elements in an array are stored in properties` this is what confuses me. What do you mean by stored in properties? What are properties? In my understanding array is just bunch of values without properties. If it they are stored in properties, how come it is not `property: value`/associative array?

Comment: This answer is particularly valuable because it explains the difference between the two notations.

Answer (score 15):

Dot notation does not work with some keywords (like `new` and `class`) in internet explorer 8.

I had this code:

```
//app.users is a hash
app.users.new = {
  // some code
}
```

And this triggers the dreaded "expected indentifier" (at least on IE8 on windows xp, I havn't tried other environments). The simple fix for that is to switch to bracket notation:

```
app.users['new'] = {
  // some code
}
```

Comment: Helpful answer. Thank You.

Comment: Works on chrome 2019 https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/image/upload/v1567651133/js.png

Answer (score 13):

Both `foo.bar` and `foo["bar"]` access a property on foo but not necessarily the same property. The difference is in how `bar` is interpreted. When using a dot, the word after the dot is the literal name of the property. When using square brackets, the expression between the brackets is evaluated to get the property name. Whereas `foo.bar` fetches the
property of value named `“bar”`  , `foo["bar"]` tries to evaluate the expression `"bar"` and uses the result, converted to a string, as the property name

### Dot Notation’s Limitation

if we take this oject :

```
const obj = {
  123: 'digit',
  123name: 'start with digit',
  name123: 'does not start with digit',
  $name: '$ sign',
  name-123: 'hyphen',
  NAME: 'upper case',
  name: 'lower case'
};
```

accessing their propriete using dot notation

```
obj.123;      // ❌ SyntaxError
obj.123name;  // ❌ SyntaxError
obj.name123;  // ✅ 'does not start with digit'
obj.$name;    // ✅  '$ sign'
obj.name-123;  // ❌ SyntaxError
obj.'name-123';// ❌ SyntaxError
obj.NAME; // ✅ 'upper case'
obj.name; // ✅ 'lower case'
```

But none of this is a problem for the Bracket Notation:

```
obj['123'];     // ✅ 'digit'
obj['123name']; // ✅ 'start with digit'
obj['name123']; // ✅ 'does not start with digit'
obj['$name'];   // ✅ '$ sign'
obj['name-123']; // ✅ 'does not start with digit'
obj['NAME']; // ✅ 'upper case'
obj['name']; // ✅ 'lower case'
```

#### accessing variable using variable :

```
const variable = 'name';
const obj = {
  name: 'value'
};
// Bracket Notation
obj[variable]; // ✅ 'value'
// Dot Notation
obj.variable; // undefined
```

Comment: Because of evaluation, could the bracket notation be slower?

Answer (score 11):

Generally speaking, they do the same job.
Nevertheless, the bracket notation gives you the opportunity to do stuff that you can't do with dot notation, like

```
var x = elem["foo[]"]; // can't do elem.foo[];
```

This can be extended to any property containing special characters.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use brackets if the property name has special characters:

```
var foo = {
    "Hello, world!": true,
}
foo["Hello, world!"] = false;
```

Other than that, I suppose it's just a matter of taste. IMHO, the dot notation is shorter and it makes it more obvious that it's a property rather than an array element (although of course JavaScript does not have associative arrays anyway).

Answer (score 9):

Be careful while using these notations:
For eg. if we want to access a function present in the parent of a window.
In IE :

```
window['parent']['func']
```

is not equivalent to

```
window.['parent.func']
```

We may either use:

```
window['parent']['func']
```

or

```
window.parent.func
```

to access it

Answer (score 9):

You have to use square bracket notation when -

1. The property name is number.

   ```
   var ob = {
     1: 'One',
     7 : 'Seven'
   }
   ob.7  // SyntaxError
   ob[7] // "Seven"
   ```
2. The property name has special character.

   ```
   var ob = {
     'This is one': 1,
     'This is seven': 7,
   }  
   ob.'This is one'  // SyntaxError
   ob['This is one'] // 1
   ```
3. The property name is assigned to a variable and you want to access the 
   property value by this variable.

   ```
   var ob = {
     'One': 1,
     'Seven': 7,
   }

   var _Seven = 'Seven';
   ob._Seven  // undefined
   ob[_Seven] // 7
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Bracket notation can use variables, so it is useful in two instances where dot notation will not work:

1) When the property names are dynamically determined (when the exact names are not known until runtime).

2) When using a for..in loop to go through all the properties of an object.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 2):

Case where `[]` notation is helpful :

If your object is dynamic and there could be some random values in keys like `number` and `[]`or any other special character, for example -

`var a = { 1 : 3 };`

Now if you try to access in like `a.1` it will through an error, because it is expecting an string over there.

Answer (score 2):

Dot notation is always preferable. If you are using some "smarter" IDE or text editor, it will show undefined names from that object. 
Use brackets notation only when you have the name with like dashes or something similar invalid. And also if the name is stored in a variable.

Comment: And there are also situations where the bracket notation is not allowed at all, even if you don't have dashes. For instance, you can write `Math.sqrt(25)`, but not `Math['sqrt'](25)`.

Comment: @MrLister `Math['sqrt'](25)` works, at least as of the latest Firefox. And as far as I know it's always worked, you can call methods with bracket notation just as easily as properties.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery just because something works doesn't mean you should do it 

Answer (score 1):

Let me add some more use case of the square-bracket notation. If you want to access a property say `x-proxy` in a object, then `-` will be interpreted wrongly. Their are some other cases too like space, dot, etc., where dot operation will not help you. Also if u have the key in a variable then only way to access the value of the key in a object is by bracket notation. Hope you get some more context.

Answer (score 1):

An example where the dot notation fails

```
json = { 
   "value:":4,
   'help"':2,
   "hello'":32,
   "data+":2,
   "":'',
   "a[]":[ 
      2,
      2
   ]
};

// correct
console.log(json['value:']);
console.log(json['help"']);
console.log(json["help\""]);
console.log(json['hello\'']);
console.log(json["hello'"]);
console.log(json["data+"]);
console.log(json[""]);
console.log(json["a[]"]);

// wrong
console.log(json.value:);
console.log(json.help");
console.log(json.hello');
console.log(json.data+);
console.log(json.);
console.log(json.a[]);
```

> The property names shouldn't interfere with the syntax rules of javascript for you to be able to access them as `json.property_name`

Answer (score 0):

Or when you want to dynamically change the classList action for an element:

```
// Correct

showModal.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => {
      changeClass(findHidden, 'remove'); // Correct
    },
    true
  );
});

//correct
function changeClass(findHidden, className) {
  for (let item of findHidden) {
    console.log(item.classList[className]('hidden'));// Correct
  }
}

// Incorrect 
function changeClass(findHidden, className) {
  for (let item of findHidden) {
    console.log(item.classList.className('hidden')); // Doesn't work
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot notation and bracket notation both are used to access the object properties in JavaScript. The dot notation is mostly used as it is easier to read and comprehend. So why should we use bracket notation and what is the difference between then? well, the bracket notation `[]` allows us to access object properties using variables because it converts the expression inside the square brackets to a string.

```js
const person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30
};

//dot notation
const nameDot = person.name;
console.log(nameDot);
// 'John'

const nameBracket = person['name'];
console.log(nameBracket);
// 'John'
```

Now, let's look at a variable example:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30
};

const myName = 'name';
console.log(person[myName]);
// 'John'
```

Another advantage is that dot notation only contain be alphanumeric (and _ and $) so for instance, if you want to access an object like the one below (contains '-', you must use the bracket notation for that)

```js
const person = {
  'my-name' : 'John'
}

console.log(person['my-name']); // 'John'
// console.log(person.my-name); // Error
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm giving another example to understand the usage differences btw them clearly. When using nested array and nested objects

```
    const myArray = [
  {
    type: "flowers",
    list: [ "a", "b", "c" ],
  },
  {
    type: "trees",
    list: [ "x", "y", "z" ],
  }
];
```

Now if we want to access the second item from the trees list `means y`.

*We can't use bracket notation all the time*

```
const secondTree = myArray[1]["list"][1]; // incorrect syntex
```

Instead, *we have to use*

```
const secondTree = myArray[1].list[1]; // correct syntex
```

Comment: That's wrong; bracket notations can do everything that dot notations can, it's even more powerful than dot notations that it can access a property name with special characters and spaces between them(*if we include strings inside brackets*), or it can use variable's value as property name(*if we omit the strings inside brackets*), whereas dot notations would try to access variable's name as property and lead to errors. Please edit your answer if you have to add more correct information or delete it as it would be misleading beginners.