# Is there any way to use a dynamic key with node-mongodb-native?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

Is there any way to use dynamic keys with the node-mongodb-native driver? By this I mean having a variable hold the key instead of using the key directly.

As in when one would normally do this:

```
db.createCollection('col', function(err, col){
    col.insert({'_id':'wak3ajakar00'});
}
```

to do this instead:

```
db.createCollection('col', function(err, col){
    var ID = '_id';
    col.insert({ID:'wak3ajakar00'});
}
```

When I run the latter code, I end up with a document in collection db.col with a key called `ID` in addition to a standardly created `_id`, as opposed to just a key `_id` with the value `wak3ajakar00`. This leads me to believe that it isn't actually possible to do this directly.

Instead, I'm now just creating the document that I want to insert ahead of time as follows:

```
db.createCollection('col', function(err, col){
    var ID = 'wak3ajakar00';
    var key = '_id';
    insertion = {}
    insertion[key] = ID;
    col.insert(insertion);
}
```

This works exactly like I want it to, but I just wanted to know if there are any better ways to go about this. JavaScript, NodeJS, and MongoDB are all new to me, so I feel like I could easily be missing something. If not, are there any cleaner ways to write the above code in JavaScript?

Best, and thanks,
 Sami

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a property to a JavaScript Object using a variable as the name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**2020 Edit:** Object literals can now be created in a couple of handy new ways:

You can now use a variable as a property name in an object literal by wrapping it in square brackets:

```
const ID = "_id";
col.insert({ [ID]: "wak3ajakar00" });
```

You can use the variable name as the property name, and the variable value as the property value in an object literal like this:

```
const _id = "wak3ajakar00";
col.insert({ _id });
```

---

*Original Answer from 2011:*

In object literal syntax, you cannot use a variable as the key name, only values.  The way to do it, is the way you already discovered - create your object first, then add the property as a separate step using square bracket notation.

```
var obj = {};
var ID = "_id";
obj[ID] = "wak3ajakar00";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small function that creates such an object

```
var obj = function(key, value, obj) {
  obj = obj || {};
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}

// Usage
foo = obj('foo' + 'bar', 'baz');
// -> {'foobar': 'baz'}

foo = obj('stack' + 'over', 'flow', foo);
// -> {'foobar': 'baz', 'stackover': 'flow'}
```

Don't know if calling this function *obj* is a good idea.