# Unable to add properties to a object using $.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a object **habits** contain some values

```
var habits={
       "Drinking":"No",
       "Smoking":"No"
       }
```

I need to add the values in this variable to another variable in this format

```
var NewHabits=new Object();
    NewHabits.Drinking="No";
    NewHabits.Smoking="No";
```

My **habits** variable is big so i decided to add values using jquery $.each() function

```
var NewHabits=new Object();
  $.each(habits,function(index, value)
{
 NewHabits.index=value;
 }
```

But after executing this code i am getting value in **NewHabits** variable as below

```
 "index":"No","index":"No"
```

the problem is giving variable like this **NewHabits.index**
Please help me to solve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a property to a Javascript Object using a variable as the name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

```
var NewHabits = {};
$.each(habits, function (key, value) {
    NewHabits[key] = value;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NMmGL/)