# Using variables to build JS Object

Tags: javascript, json, html

I want to create an object that has some keys which come from a variable parameter. 
Let's say for example that prod_id below is a variable containing some value... I want to create an object which has an attribute with key of that 'prod_id' and value of 1.  However this does not work? Is this possible to achieve? if so, how? thanks a heaps

```
var cart_obj;
  cart_obj = {
  prod_id : 1
};
localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart_obj));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a property to a Javascript Object using a variable as the name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: ...and searching gives us [this previous question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name). Amazing, what a search can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with a simple object literal. You can do this however:

```
var cart_obj = {};
cart_obj[prod_id] = 1;
```

JavaScript object literal syntax makes no provisions for expressions on the left side of a property declaration stanza.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cart_obj = {};
cart_obj.prod_id = 1;
```

or

```
var cart_obj = {};
cart_obj[prod_id] = 1;
```