# Pass function parameters as part of instruction

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I would like to pass function parameters as parts of my function code.

```
function update(value, key) {
    $localStorage.key = value;
}
```

If I call my function with, lets say :

```
update(20, age);
```

The value (20) will be correctly used, but the key will be treated as 'key' not as 'age', thus saving content in a wrong object reference.

Any idea for a quick fix ?

Comment: `$localStorage[key] = value`

Comment: Maybe better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Comment: Thanks a lot Frédéric & georg. It works now.