# jQuery push multiple objects to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Create an array for each country 'item_location' and push object values with 'item_location' as the key.

**e.g**

```
[{USA:1},{USA:2}], [{UK:1},{UK:2}], [{CUBA:1},{CUBA:2}]
```

**or**

**e.g**

```
[
 {
  USA: {"Activity/Adventure": 1, "Beach Escape": 2}, 
  UK: {"Activity/Adventure": 1, "Beach Escape": 2}, 
  CUBA: {"Activity/Adventure": 1, "Beach Escape": 2}
 }
]
```

**Current Problems:**
The object key says 'item_location' instead of picking up the 'item_location' var value 'item.Location'.

```
  var filter = [];
  for(var ix = 0; ix < jsonData.length; ix++)
    {
      var item = jsonData[ix];
      var item_location = item.Location;
      var item_ = [{item_location:item["Activity/Adventure"]},{item_location:item["Beach Escape"]}];
      filter.push({item_});
    }
  console.log(filter);
```

[image]

**ANWSER:**

```
function filterData(){
  var filter = [];
  for(var ix = 0; ix < jsonData.length; ix++)
    {
      var item = jsonData[ix];
      var item_location = item.Location;
      var item1 = {}, item2= {};

      item1[item_location] = item["Activity/ Adventure"];
      item2[item_location] = item["Beach Escape"];
      var item_ = [item1, item2];

      filter.push(item_);
    }
  console.log(filter);
}
```

Comment: Is that one array of arrays, or multiple arrays each containing two objects? And what does the `jsonData` object contain?

Comment: This has been surely answered here. But a quick solution : Use `item_[item_location] = item[".."]` .. and so on. Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/a/695053/3639582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is `item_location` because that's what you set it to.  You cannot use variables as key names in an object literal.

You'd need to make a new object, then use the `obj[key]` syntax to add the key.

```
var item_location = item.Location;
var item1 = {}, item2= {};

item1[item_location] = item["Activity/Adventure"];
item2[item_location] = item["Beach Escape"];
var item_ = [item1, item2];

filter.push(item_);
```

Comment: Missing: var item = jsonData[ix]; but once added this worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: @adamkwadsworth: You're welcome.  Guess I just missed copying & pasting a few lines from the original question :-P