# Can not add key dynamically in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to add a key dynamically to an obj but I keep getting error "**Can not set property of undefined**" 
But I cant decalre these properties before knowing them. I want them to added dynamically as a key to that object.

```
var dict = {}
 objectarray.forEach((item: Obj) => {
        this.dict[item.ID] = "xyz";
    });
```

As per [How do I add a property to a Javascript Object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name) it seems possible to add property to object dynamically just by using obj[name] = value.

Am I missing something ? Any help ?

Comment: The problem is not that you can't set a property like that, the problem is that you are trying to set a property of "undefined". this.dict is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `this` in `this.dict` and you should be golden!

```
var dict = {}
objectarray.forEach((item: Obj) => {
   dict[item.ID] = "xyz";
});
```

Without seeing more of the code it's hard to say what `this` means in this context, but most likely it's the window object, so what you're saying is basically `window.dict[item.ID] = "xyz"`. Since there's no `dict` property on the window it'll blow up like that.

Answer (score 0):

@Oskar's answer is correct.

Here is a more verbose code sample;

```
enum memberTypes
{
    None,
    Property,
    Method
}

class memberInfo {
    memberName: string;
    memberType: memberTypes;
    constructor(name: string, mtype: memberTypes)
    {
        this.memberName = name;
        this.memberType = mtype;
    }   
    toString() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}

class propertyInfo extends memberInfo
{
    constructor(name: string) 
    {       
        super(name, memberTypes.Property);
    }   
}

class methodInfo extends memberInfo
{
    constructor(name: string) 
    {       
        super(name, memberTypes.Method);
    }   
}

var dict = new Object();
var objectArray = new Array<memberInfo>();

objectArray.push(new propertyInfo("Name"), new methodInfo("toString"));

objectArray.forEach((item) => { 
    if (item.memberType === memberTypes.Property)
    {
        if (item.memberName === "Name") {
            dict[item.memberName] = 'SysName';
        }       
    } else if (item.memberType === memberTypes.Method) {

        if (item.memberName === "toString") {
            dict[item.memberName] = function() { return JSON.stringify(this); };
        }
    }   
    console.log(item.toString());
})

console.log(dict);
```

[TypeScript Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0Aenum%20memberTypes%0A%7B%0A%09None%2C%0A%09Property%2C%0A%09Method%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20memberInfo%20%7B%0A%09memberName%3A%20string%3B%0A%09memberType%3A%20memberTypes%3B%0A%09constructor(name%3A%20string%2C%20mtype%3A%20memberTypes)%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09this.memberName%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%09%09this.memberType%20%3D%20mtype%3B%0A%09%7D%09%0A%09toString()%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20JSON.stringify(this)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20propertyInfo%20extends%20memberInfo%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string)%20%0A%09%7B%09%09%0A%09%09super(name%2C%20memberTypes.Property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%09%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20methodInfo%20extends%20memberInfo%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3A%20string)%20%0A%09%7B%09%09%0A%09%09super(name%2C%20memberTypes.Method)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%09%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20dict%20%3D%20new%20Object()%3B%0Avar%20objectArray%20%3D%20new%20Array%3CmemberInfo%3E()%3B%0A%0AobjectArray.push(new%20propertyInfo(%22Name%22)%2C%20new%20methodInfo(%22toString%22))%3B%0A%0AobjectArray.forEach((item)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%09%0A%09if%20(item.memberType%20%3D%3D%3D%20memberTypes.Property)%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09if%20(item.memberName%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22Name%22)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09dict%5Bitem.memberName%5D%20%3D%20'SysName'%3B%0A%09%09%7D%09%09%0A%09%7D%20else%20if%20(item.memberType%20%3D%3D%3D%20memberTypes.Method)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%09%09if%20(item.memberName%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22toString%22)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09dict%5Bitem.memberName%5D%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20return%20JSON.stringify(this)%3B%20%7D%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%09%0A%09console.log(item.toString())%3B%0A%7D)%0A%0Aconsole.log(dict)%3B%0Adocument.writeln(dict.toString())%3B%0A)

Comment: updated, I declared `dict` to be an `Array<string>` initially, which is quite improper considering the overall intention here...