# Using a parameter in an inner method callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, parameter-passing

So I have a function I am creating for a Chrome extension...

```
// scrape/get all the cookies
    function scrape_cookie(activeTabId, userType) {
        chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function (cookies) {
            var object = {
                userType : cookies
            };
            setUser(object, function () { getUsers(); } );
        });
    }
```

I can't get the parameter 'userType' from the outer function to be used as the property name in the object that I am creating. Instead when I read back the object it uses the actual word 'userType' instead of whatever that parameter variable is supposed to represent.

I think its probably a simple javascript technique to solve this but I can't figure it out.

Comment: [**How do I add a property to a Javascript Object using a variable as the name**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: Apologies I didnt find that duplicate, your answer was perfect thankyou.