# How can I create interchangeable instructions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="#F00";
```

This statement styles the body background color as red.

In my original code I have a function that assigns elements by tag name to a global variable `element`. I've found after calling this function I can do this: `element.style.backgroundColor="#F00";`

However, there doesn't seem to be ANY way to substitute for the property section of the statement. Below I've produced the most obvious approach, though I have also tried assigning the parameters to variables and various combinations of quotation.

```js
function assignStyle(value) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = value;
}

function attemptStyle(property,value) {
  document.body.style.property = value;
}
```

```css
button { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<button onmouseover="assignStyle('#131519');" onmouseout="assignStyle('#FFF');">
  function assignStyle(value){}
</button><br />

<button onmouseover="attemptStyle('backgroundColor','#137619');" onmouseout="attemptStyle('backgroundColor','#FFF');">
function attemptStyle(property,value){}
</button>
```

**Edit:** This question is not a duplicate of [How do I add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name).
That question contains jQuery, which many people, including myself, know literally nothing about. My question is concerned with basic JavaScript. Also, I want to know how to add a property to an element, and so by means of passing an argument to a function parameter. As far as I'm concerned, variables complicate the question further.

Comment: Its still a dupe; yes it contains jquery.  The accepted answer however does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not too certain of what you mean by "substituting" `backgroundColor`, but I'll wager a guess that you're trying to access the `backgroundColor` property programmatically. If so, your second function needs the following amendment:

```
function attemptStyle(property,value){
  document.body.style[property]=value;
}
```

Thus, if you call `attemptStyle('backgroundColor', 'red')`, you will make the background color of the document red.

Comment: So brackets then... like accessing an iteration or index. Is that what's happening there? I noticed there is no period between style and property.

Comment: Correct. Square brackets can either be used to access an element in an array, or a property of an object. You could even do things like `someObject[prop1][prop2][prop3]` to go 3 levels deep.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question, but can fix your problem. You are trying to change colors when the mouse is over an element. This can be done simply with *CSS*

```
<style>
button {
    background-color:#fff;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #131519
}
</style>

<button>
function assignStyle(value){}
</button><br />

<button>
function attemptStyle(param,value){}
</button>
```

Comment: The mouse over thing was just so I didn't need to add a reset button to the snippet. The question was intended to explain that I needed a way to change the property target of a line of JavaScript instruction inside a function