# How can I call an object method using a function argument?

Tags: javascript, html

So I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109817/how-can-i-create-interchangeable-instructions) before... I wanted to know how to argue for the css property in a `document`*.element*`.style`*.property=value*. The solution was simple, and almost made sense --but clearly I didn't understand it entirely or I'd know trying the same solution for *.element* doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
function appendElement(handle){

 element=document[handle]('div');
 document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

This way I could choose to create a new element or shift an existing one based on id or class or index appearance or whatever. Of course even without knowing the correct way to do this, the code I have above looks wrong to me, but it's the best I can do without some assistance.

**EDIT:** Test case

```js
/* The core instructions */
element=document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(element);


/* the choosy version */
function appendElement(handle){
element=document[handle]('div');
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
appendElement(createElement);
element.innerHTML="third text";


/* SHOULD move the 'text' div under the 'third text' div*/
appendElement(getElementById('first'));
```

```html
<div id="first">text</div>
<div>second text</div>
```

Comment: You want to choose an existing element or create a new one if it doesn't exist based on a selector passed to the function?

Comment: I don't understand what you expect *element* to be here. If it's indeed a property of `document`, then your code will work. If it's not a property of document, then your notional code `document`*.element*`.style` seems wrong (i.e., indicates something different from what you really want).

Comment: if handle is a function name and its a method of document, you are doing it well... but i don't know what is handle, if it is a function, can you put it with the explanation code?

Comment: So like you could write, document.getElementById() or document.createElement(), for example. At least that's the idea.

Comment: @Masixauce3000 then you should pass the string `"getElementById"` to the function

Comment: @gabrielperales yes when I return to my desk

Comment: @Musixauce3000 — It still isn't very clear. Please try creating a *complete* test case — http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve — and tell us what the expected input and output of the function call should be.

Comment: Did you try the code of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35185458/1463630)? Let me know if you already have solved your question.

Comment: @gabrielperales I accepted and up-voted your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Edit

In this line `appendElement(getElementById('first'));`you are not passing a function as you want, you are passing the result of call `undefined` with the param `'first'`, because it can't find a function in that context or a global function called `getElementById` (so it will be `undefined`), furthermore your are trying to execute `undefined` passing it a string... this is going to raise an error, and in the case in which function existed (i.e you pass `document.getElementById('first')`), then you will be passing the returned value of executing that function instead of the function.

If you want to pass a function you *should pass a function*, thats is `appendElement(document.getElementById)`, without calling it with an argument, but I think you are going to need to pass a selector to that function to accomplish what you are trying to do. So
the code will be something like this:

```js
function appendElement(handle, selector){
  element=handle.call(document, selector);
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

appendElement(document.getElementById, 'first');
```

```html
<div id="first">text</div>
<div>second text</div>
```

call allows you to execute a function as a method and specify which object will be the receptor of that calling. [Here is more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to use `document.` in the argument, but I think if I ponder on this answer long enough it will come to me why that isn't possible.

Answer (score -3):

I didn't understand your need.

But, if `handle` is equals to 'createElement', which is a property of `document`, your code will run.