# How to dynamically add to an object javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object:

```
var someObject={};
```

and i have a function that adds to the object:

```
function add(id, firstName){
    //stuff that makes sure id and firstName are correct format and stuff and say if firstName is john and id is I23423
    someObject.id=firstName;
}
```

but it always output as

```
someObject{
    id="john"
}
```

but I want the id to be whatever the user inputs the id as, so the output will be

```
someObject{
    I23423="John"
}
```

what do I add/change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Comment: do you mean `someObject[id]=firstName;`?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you want, you need to use `[]` on the object almost like it was an array. I honestly don't know the reason why, but this is how you do it.

```js
function(id,name){
  var obj = {};
  //whatever other things you need;
  obj[id] = name;
  return obj;
  }
```