# How to dynamically pass keys for data option in ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass dynamically keys for `data` option into ajax call.

`data:{action:'add',id:10},`

Actually I'm trying to create global function, which can be use for all tables for disable the specific rows `onClick` event. For that purpose I need to add different actions and table column names for calling php function. So i want to pass keys also as well as values.

### JS Function

```
function globalDisable(id,table_column,call_action){
    // call_action is use for calling the related php function
    // table_column is use for calling the column name of that table
    action_parm = {call_action:'disable',table_column:id}
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'post.php',
        data:action_parm,
        success: function(response){
        }
    });
}
```

### Call JS Function

```
onclick="return globalDisable(10,'user_id','disableUser');"
```

### Php Script

```
$disableUser  = (isset($_REQUEST['disableUser']))? (string)$_REQUEST['disableUser']:'not';
if($disableUser != 'not'){
    $response->disArea($user_id);
}
```

When I run the function, in console doesn't changing its remains same `call_action=disable&table_column=10`.

So is this possible to pass dynamically keys for data option in ajax call? I would like to appreciate if someone guide me regarding this. Thank You

Comment: parameters should be in same order while calling function.

Comment: Use the debugger in your browser to **look at** the HTTP data which is being sent to the host. You should immediately recognize what the trouble is ... The data is not being sent to the host in the manner that your host-side code *(as written)* expects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a property to a JavaScript Object using a variable as the name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: show the row with function called

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `action_parm = {call_action:'disable',table_column:id}`, write:

```
var action_param = {};
action_param[call_action]='disable';
action_param[table_column]='id';
```

See: [How do I add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Comment: How it will be add next to `data:{action_param}` ?

Comment: And that will produce `disableUser = "disable"` ... not really useful

Comment: The question was : `So is this possible to pass dynamically keys for data option in ajax call?`

Comment: @SparK Because of this check in the php script `isset($_REQUEST['disableUser'])` the submitted parameter should be `disableUser` which is the value of `call_action` in `globalDisable(10,'user_id','disableUser')`. And that's the result of the code in this answer.

Comment: @Andreas what's really confusing is the tableColumn part receiving a number... that would produce `1="id"`. Upvoting anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing your action as a parameter to the function but then not using it in the ajax call

```
function globalDisable(id,table_column,call_action){
    // call_action is use for calling the related php function
    // table_column is use for calling the column name of that table

    //action_parm = {call_action:'disable',table_column:id}
    var action_parm = {call_action: call_action,
                       table_column: table_column, 
                       user_id: id};
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'post.php',
        data:action_parm,
        success: function(response){
        }
    });
}
```

You could do this like this, maybe you will find it easier to read

```
function globalDisable(id,table_column,call_action){
    // call_action is use for calling the related php function
    // table_column is use for calling the column name of that table

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'post.php',
        data:{ call_action: call_action,
               table_column: table_column, 
               user_id: id
             },
        success: function(response){
        }
    });
}
```

Also in the PHP you are testing for the wrong parameter in $_REQUEST

```
$disableUser  = (isset($_REQUEST['call_action']))? (string)$_REQUEST['call_action'] : 'not';
if($disableUser != 'not'){
    $response->disArea($user_id);
}
```

Comment: Its giving me undefined error `ReferenceError: action_param is not defined`

Comment: It does not give me correct result in the console, I'm calling the function `return globalDisable(1, 'user_id', 'disArea');` and this is the result `call_action=disArea&table_column=1`

Comment: Thats sorrect for what you have coded. I assume you want 3 parameters passed, and you have put `id` in the wrong parameter, give me 2 mins to have a guess at what you want to do

Comment: Check the changes to the javascript, now passing **3** parameters. I am guessing a littel becasue you have not shown all your PHP code