# Trying to query mongoose with variable as key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I query mongodb using a variable as the key I'm searching for?

The data:

```
const schedule = {
  day0: [10, 1440],
  day1: [10, 1440],
  day3: [10, 1440],
  day6: [10, 1440],
}
```

The query

```
User.find({ `schedule.${varHere}` { $exists: true}}, (err, users) => {
  console.log(users)
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a property to a JavaScript Object using a variable as the name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set up a object first either using [ES6 computed propery names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```
const query = { [`schedule.${varHere}`]: { $exists : true } };
```

or using an expression as a property name

```
const query = {};
query[`schedule.${varHere}`] = { $exists: true };
```

then

```
User.find(query, (err, users) => {
  console.log(users)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much man
     User.find({[`schedule.${day}`]:  {$exists: true}}, (err, users) => {
      console.log(users)
    })
worked like a charm