# How to create an object with dynamic property names

Tags: javascript

So, I want to have an object with dynamic property names, retrieving from an array. This is what I've tried so far:

```
var fruits = {};

var props = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana'];

for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
  fruits.props[i] = 'Juice';
}
```

My object should look like this:

```
fruits { orange: 'Juice', apple: 'Juice', banana: 'Juice' };
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined(…)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Not because the question title is similar, the question itself has to be as well. This question is different from [695050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name) because I'm not retrieving my property names from the DOM. I'm trying to loop an array and it tends to cause a confusion when working with the brackets notation.

Comment: `fruits[props[i]] = 'Juice';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `fruits.props[i] = 'Juice';` would try to set the 0th index value of `props` property where the property is `undefined` and causing the error.

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) for assigning object property using a string.

```js
var fruits = {};

var props = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana'];

for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
  fruits[props[i]] = 'Juice';
  //----^^^^^^^^^^-----
}

console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 3):

`fruits.props[i] = 'Juice';`

Needs to be:  `fruits[props[i]] = 'Juice';`

Because using dot notation, you cannot use a dynamic property name, but with bracket notation, the property is expected to be a string and that string can be a literal or a dynamically gotten value.

Comment: Upvoted for the bracket notation explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You need the key in brackets, read more about [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> object.property
> object["property"]
> ```

```js
var fruits = {};

var props = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana'];

for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    fruits[props[i]] = 'Juice';
    //    ^        ^
}

console.log(fruits);
```