# Dynamically store new object property values in for...in loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node application running express and I want to escape apostrophes on the incoming request body properties, but I'm not confident this is the best way to do it.

```
exports.p_edit = function(req, res) {

    var args = [
        req.body.title.split("'").join("\\'"),
        req.files.thumbnail.name.split("'").join("\\'"),
        req.body.tags.split("'").join("\\'"),
        req.body.topic.split("'").join("\\'"),
        req.body.preview.split("'").join("\\'"),
        req.body.markdown.split("'").join("\\'")
    ];
    // ...
    // Do other stuff
```

I know I can use a `for(prop in req.body)` loop to iterate over the all request body properties, but how can I reassign the values dynamically to each property?

For example if I do

```
for(prop in req.body) {
    prop.split("'").join("\\'");
}
```

and later reference `req.body.title` (or any property), then the value is unchanged. Similarly, if I try to assign it like `req.body.prop = prop.split("'").join("\\'");` (hoping that `req.body.prop` would change dynamically with each iteration) it simply adds the `prop` property to the `req.body` object. How can I dynamically iterate and reassign these properties?

Comment: [Try bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name) – `req.body[prop] = req.body[prop].split("'").join("\\'");`

Comment: Why do you need/want to escape them? Normally you only need this if you  e.g. pass them to a database or similar and for such a case those libs communicating with a service that requires escaping normally provide a better way to do that.

Comment: @t.niese What do you suggest doing? Most places I've looked online simply suggest stripping them out with something like what I've done.

Comment: Where do you use the data that requires the escaping of the `'`? Without knowing the later usage or the reason why you escape them it is not possibel to tell. But I never need to do that manually in any of my applications, because this was covered by the the corresponding libraries in a more reliable and saver way. Libraries that require escaping should know better what to and how to escape correctly and therefore in normaly provider those functionalities that should be used instead of own code.

Comment: @t.niese I am doing a variety of things with the values, but they do get stored in a `mysql` db. I'm using the mysql npm module, but it doesn't escape them on its own. Is there a method within the module to sanitize input more reliably?

Comment: The mysql module does provide functionality to escape [values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#escaping-query-values) and [identfiers](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#escaping-query-identifiers) by either using the escape function or by placeholders (`?`) in the query. And you should always use those functionality over your own one.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you. This is better.

Comment: if you use the escape function then keep the escaping close to the place where you use it in the query. In generel it would suggest to only use the placeholders, or if you compose the query using `+` that you escape the values directly at this place, otherwise your code will not be easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you just need to change your loop to use bracket notation:

```
for(var prop in req.body) {
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        req.body[prop] = req.body[prop].split("'").join("\\'");
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wsahkozt/1/

Comment: How about adding hasOwnProperty check?

Comment: I suppose that's commonsense enough to add, even if it wasn't specified in the question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I did not know you could use square bracket notation here. Thanks!