# Is it possible to get value from array to assign data name in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know how to loop through array to get value... but I don't know how to use it to assign data name in ajax.  is it possible to do this?

```
<script>
    var my_array = ["orange", "apple", "banana"];

    $.post(url, {
    orange: 'orange',     //I want to use value in array to define data name in ajax
    apple: 'apple',
    banana : 'banana' 
    }, function (data) {

                alert("Success Post Data!");
                });
            });
```

/////// so I want something like this

```
    $.post(url, {
    my_arr[0]: 'my_arr[0]',    
    my_arr[1]: 'my_arr[1]',
    my_arr[2] : 'my_arr[2]',
    .......................
    my_arr[n] :  'my_arr[n] 
    }, function (data) {

                alert("Success Post Data!");
                });
            });
```

but don't know how to do it.  How could I do?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Are you asking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)?

Comment: Don't undo constructive edits. Tags don't go in titles. We have tags for that.

Comment: **Again:** Are you asking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, its possible:

```
var my_array = ["orange", "apple", "banana"];
var dataToSend = {};
my_array.forEach(function(d){
   dataToSend[d] = d;
});
$.post(url, dataToSend, function (data) {
      alert("Success Post Data!");
    });
});
```

Comment: We don't need yet another answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name).

Answer (score 1):

Create a object first and the post
what i understand u want the value of ur array as key

```
var postObject = {};
postObject[my_arr[0]] = 'my_arr[0]';
...
postObject[my_arr[n]] = 'my_arr[n]';
```

then post that object

```
$.post(url, postObject, function (data) {

                alert("Success Post Data!");
                });
            });
```

Comment: We don't need yet another answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name).