# Use property of object as key inside another object, SyntaxError: missing : after

Tags: javascript

I would like to specify one of the keys for `options` to be a value from my `constants` object but cannot use dot notation inside object declaration.

Is there a shorthand way of doing this without declaring an additional variable before `options` only to hold the value?

Error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

Code:

```
var constants = {
  KEY: 'Content-Type'
}

var options = {
    constants.KEY: 'application/json'
};
alert(options);
```

Comment: try this `[constants.KEY]: 'application/json`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a property to a JavaScript object using a variable as the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name of the key is dynamic, you can set the key like the following:

```
var options = {
   [constants.KEY]: 'application/json'
 };
```