# variable amount of optional parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, optional-parameters, jconfirm

Im using this tool here http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#dialog and i wanted to have a popup that has a variable amount of buttons based on a piece of data used to construct pop up.

Here is an example of what a very simple/empty one looks like.

```
$.confirm({
    title: 'testing',
    content: 'this has two static buttons',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
        },
        cancel: function () {
        },
    }
});
```

What i want is to be able to put a foreach loop in side of "buttons: { ... }".

Is there a way to do so or a way to achieve what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just build your options object before :

```
var options = {
    title: 'testing',
    content: 'this has two static buttons',
    buttons: {},
};

$.each( variable_name, function(){
    options.buttons[ this.btn_name ] = this.fn;
} );

$.confirm( options );
```

Of course, everything depends on how the object you loop looks like, but the logic is here.

Comment: Thanks, this is likely what I'm going to end up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is inverted.  The following is an object:

```
{
    title: 'testing',
    content: 'this has two static buttons',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
        },
        cancel: function () {
        },
    }
}
```

So you could do:

```
var options = {
    title: 'testing',
    content: 'this has two static buttons',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
        },
        cancel: function () {
        },
    }
};
$.confirm(options);
```

You then can add items by

```
options.buttons["mybutton"] = function() { };
```

You can place the previous code in a loop and change the string "mybutton" to whatever you want for whatever functions you have.  You're basically asking [how to add a property to and existing javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name).

Comment: Thanks.

Im super new to javascript/jquery and i did not understand what this syntax was.

knowing that is a short hand way of building an object helps alot.