# Struggling with Javascript Object Array adding keys

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet of code:

```
var arrLiteData = [];
for(ii=0;ii<10;ii++)
{
  arrLiteData.push({ii:{"field1":100,"field2":ii}});
}
```

...but instead of ii taking the increasing numeric value of ii, the array just holds the actual variable name, like this:

```
[{"ii":{"field1":100,"field2":0}},{"ii":{"field1":100,"field2":1}}...etc, etc...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: after it works, you may consider to change the data structure, because you always need to know which key you have. it makes an overhead which could be saved.

Comment: Re the dupetarget, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31024830/157247) is the most directly applicable.

Comment: Thanks guys! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes are optional for javascript object keys, so
`{ii:{"field1":100,"field2":ii}}` is the same as 
`{"ii":{"field1":100,"field2":ii}}` or even
`{ii:{field1:100,field2:ii}}`. They are just need if you have non alphanumeric characters.

To solve this you could either use a computed key if you're transpiling your code or targeting recent navigators:

`{[ii]:{"field1":100,"field2":ii}}`

Or build the object in two steps:

```
var arrLiteData = [];
for(ii=0;ii<10;ii++)
{
  var obj = {};
  obj[ii] = {"field1":100,"field2":ii};
  arrLiteData.push(obj);
}
```